# What's up with the Suggested Edits queue?

Tags: bug, status-completed, suggested-edits, review

I'm assuming that some changes are under way, and I hope they're not done yet because I've been getting constant errors with this new queue.

> An error occurred when reviewing this item. Please try again. (click
>   on this box to dismiss)

I know the old queue had room for improvement, but this seems like a step backwards. I can only see one item at a time which feels limiting, and most of the time I'm getting an error when accepting or rejecting a suggested edit.

What's going on?

Comment: It's a work in progress...

Comment: Actions seem to take effect though. I quite like the interface, just needs a bit of polish.

Comment: Looks like it saved the action - happened to me too but upon reload it looks OK.

Comment: The [old one's](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits?s=1&pagesize=15&filter=day) still working if you want to use that. Or was I not meant to say?

Comment: Well, yes, "broken" was not quite what we had in mind.  We're looking into it...

Comment: We have pushed a fixed for this but will leave this question open until we turn the review dashboard back on and get additional feedback.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This was a bad bug: if your approval/rejection vote wasn't "final", then you would see a generic error popup, even though your vote was successful.

It's fixed now. Thanks for the feedback, and please [leave more if you notice any other issues](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/139536/new-feature-community-review-tasks-now-in-beta).