# New Feature: Community Review Tasks - Now in Beta

Tags: discussion, review

**Please post new bug reports, feature requests or discussions as individual questions tagged with at least [review](/questions/tagged/review) in addition to the requisite**

And thanks for all the great feedback so far!

---

We are currently soliciting feedback for an improved version of /review to help with the very important task of maintaining site quality.  There are three targeted tasks we have built thus far and will continue to roll out others after we gain confidence these three are working:

- ***Low Quality Posts***:  This task targets posts that we've algorithmically determined to be low quality.  Your job is to read these posts and:

  - decide if a post does in fact **Look Good**
  - **Edit** the post to make it better
  - **Delete**<sup>1</sup> the post entirely
  - or skip it if you are **Not Sure**.

  The minimum reputation to perform this task corresponds with the ability to edit any post (currently 2,000).
- ***Suggested Edits***:  This task targets posts edited by users who have not yet earned the reputation to fully edit.  Your job is to read these edits and:

  - decide to **Approve** the edit as is
  - **Reject** the edit
  - **Edit** the original post and make your own edit
  - **Delete** the post (moderator only)
  - or skip it if you are **Not Sure**.

  The minimum reputation to perform this task corresponds with the ability to edit any post (currently 2,000).
- ***Close Votes***: This task targets posts that have received at least one close vote.  These posts generally need additional review to help decide if a post does in fact require closure.  Your job is to read these posts and:

  - decide to **Close** this post by casting another close vote
  - **Do Not Close**<sup>2</sup> this post if do not agree with the reasons for closing
  - **Edit** this post to make it better
  - or skip it if you are **Not Sure**.

  The minimum reputation to perform this task corresponds with the ability to cast close votes (currently 3,000).

Each of the actions on the review task listed above may not always be available based on your current reputation or moderator status.  We will be reviewing the data collected in this experiment closely to determine if these new review tasks are working and also reserve the right to pull these tasks out entirely if we find they are not.  We have enabled these review tasks on Meta, Super User, Server Fault, and Stack Overflow.

To check out the new hotness visit:  https://meta.stackoverflow.com/review

<sup>1 If you don't have enough rep to delete, you can "Recommend Deletion".  This doesn't do anything right now except move it to the front of the queue for people who *can* delete it.</sup>
<sup>2 "Do Not Close" just removes it from the queue right now -- it doesn't affect close votes.</sup>

Comment: For suggested edits, you don't mention the **Improve** functionality, yet the description for the suggested edits task reads: *Approve, reject, or **improve** edits suggested by users.*

Comment: @animuson - I am assuming the _edit_ option is what was _improve_.

Comment: @Oded: But the text about reads: *Edit the **original post** and make your own edit* - That doesn't sound like improving the edit to me.

Comment: @animuson - OK. Missed that. You are right.

Comment: Will the old options (esp. Late Answer) be kept, if the feature is rolled out completely?

Comment: @nhahtdh: "These will soon be moved to the new beta Review Task system" - So yes.

Comment: What happens with "Not Sure?" What if you want to come back to it later? There doesn't seem to be a mechanism for un-dequeuing a post.

Comment: There is currently a single "suggested edits pending approval" highlight on the header - it leads me to an [_empty_ page](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/review-beta/suggested-edits). I am assuming it is a related bug.

Comment: What happened to badge progress?

Comment: @octopusgrabbus you are still making progress.  We will add this back to the new review task soon.

Comment: [cross-posted from SF.chat] You need 2000 rep to use the first two links. I have 1.4k rep on SF with 400 helpful flags. I'm going to still have to use the "old" links until they get move or I get more rep. I'm not expecting for the whole system to be changed but could they be made avalible to those with 2000k rep *or* 250+ helpful flags? That number demonstatres a decent understand of the flagging system.

Comment: Are there 85,3k CloseVotes or 85,3k questions with at least one close vote? The second metric would make more sense.

Comment: Isn't a required rep of 2000 a bit excessive. Its not like a 1000 rep user wouldn't be able to tell if a question was low quality or not.

Comment: -1 (but can't due to not enough rep here, what a pity ...) Reason is well presented in @EJB answer http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/139604/159794

Comment: just a small glitch: window has no title (just the page URL in Firefox)

Comment: With such high rep limits, review might start stalling, especially on AskUbuntu, where panicky users are great in number, and returning users are few.

Comment: Just want to say that I really like the direction the review workflow has headed. Usability while reviewing was probably my biggest (of few) gripes with SO, so I'm super-excited. A **huge thank you** to the team for this.

Comment: The close vote tab is nice, gives an easy view on what other users vote to close. I always thought I was a bit trigger-happy, but I now know that at least I am not alone.

Comment: The "not sure" option rubs me the wrong way. Makes me doubt myself sometimes when all I want to do is move on. Couldn't it say "Pass" or "Skip" instead?

Comment: @j08691 I've had the same thought a couple times... but really, how often do you want to skip when "I don't know what to do with this" isn't the reason? Sometimes I want to skip because I don't feel like reading an especially long question or because I don't want to think about a particularly convoluted post, but those are actually both just subcategories of "not sure."

Comment: @PopularDemand - Yeah I had the same thought, although "not sure" connotes a meaning behind the action whereas "skip" or "pass" simply denote the action of moving onto the next review item.

Comment: @j08691: to me, it indicates a certain finality that isn't there with "skip". Which is desirable - you can't go back after all. Well, you can, but you can't go back and choose another option - if you're not sure, you can't go back and change your mind later, which I would expect; if you skip it, you can't go back and close or edit or approve it later, which I wouldn't expect. This is the issue I always had with the old review page: once I clicked "review this", it was off my list, regardless of whether or not I did anything else - but I always felt like I *had* to do something else still.

Comment: I like it, great idea!!! One comment: the close vote tab should have a big warning: CAUTION, USING THIS FEATURE CAN REALLY RUIN YOUR DAY (and an ad of the leading antidepressants brand). It's really depressing to see the amount of crap coming by when doing it for half an hour. Worse than the "low quality posts". Ehh, I guess it works...

Comment: @Gert: that's not a terrible idea... I know I can't spend too much time wading through the 10K/mod tools without sinking into despair. Maybe when you run out of close votes it should automatically redirect you to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/greatest-hits... er...

Comment: I'm a <2K user and I like the old system as it is. I couldn't access to any of these new sections, only to the statistics. Why? That would be my "don't like, stay with old". And of course, I couldn't test any new feature.

Comment: This way is far more effective and addictive than before.  I find myself spending more time looking at the question, and spending more time than in the previous version!

Comment: A question should not be closed, deleted or migrated after 5 days from the time it was posted. This provides sufficient time for reviewing the question. If someone votes to close a question, they should be required to post a comment as to why it should be closed to allow the user to edit or delete the question. Thank You!

Comment: Any feedback from development team on what improvements they are doing or even just responses to the comments and answers here?

Comment: Is there a planned date for when all sites are getting the new review format?

Comment: @Mark: I've tried to add comments to the answers we're either considering or have decided against doing. We'll continue going through the suggestions here, but should probably close this soon in favor of individual [bug] / [feature-request] posts - a huge thanks to you all for the great feedback!

Comment: @Shog9 SU seems to be well under way to end up with an empty queue in about a month. Do you guys plan to fill it up by dialing up the requirements a notch or would that be status-completed?

Comment: @Ivo: can't it be both? (But yeah, I want to dial down the per-queue limits considerably once folks have had a chance to rip through the backlogs)

Comment: Any idea when this goes live through the network?

Comment: Just now @Dynamic

Comment: [Is the close system working as expected?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/143404/is-the-close-system-working-as-expected)

Answer (score 67):

So I've been reviewing low quality posts on SO. There are four options:

- Looks Good
- Edit
- Recommend Deletion
- Not Sure

What about if I want to recommend an answer be turned into a comment? I've seen many so-called answers which would be useful as comments instead of just being deleted.

[image: recommend convert to comment]

Comment: Conversion to comment requires full community moderator status.  This is one reason a flag option should be included.

Comment: So add a Recommended Convert to comment for regular users and Convert to comment for full mods. Problem solved

Comment: @IvoFlipse Exactly what I meant.

Comment: Convert to Comment *should* be very rare. Yes, a lot of people leave comments as answers - but that doesn't make them good comments. I've also seen "not an answer" flags being used as an attempt to deny rep for answers that ARE ANSWERS, but which the flagger feels are unworthy for whatever reason (incorrect, too simple, link-only, etc) - moving a poor answer into a comment doesn't fix anything. I'm not completely against providing an option for this *if it's really necessary*, but so far all of the examples I've seen should've been left alone or deleted.

Comment: @Shog9 Especially with trouble-shooting questions on SU, many "answers" are actually asking for more information. They'd otherwise be flagged not an answer and hopefully converted to a comment

Comment: @Daniel: worth noting that in the context of the LQ queue, these comments-as-answers would only appear when very short (and/or very badly written). Even if we introduce LQ-flags into the mix, that shouldn't be picking up these "not an answer" answers.

Comment: @Shog9 "Did you try to X your Y?" isn't an answer, but might be useful to keep as a comment for certain questions.

Comment: @Daniel: if that's worth keeping in any form (that is, if "Your Y isn't sufficiently X'd - X your Y by doing Z to resolve the problem." is a valid answer) then it's probably worth encouraging the author to expand on it rather than deleting / converting to a comment. But, this really depends on the situation - in particular, a request for more info converted 5 minutes after it was posted with no response from the OP is rather different from a "have you tried" posted a year ago with "Nope - thanks, that did it!" as the response.

Answer (score 60):

Not sure if anyone mentioned this, but "Low Quality Posts" could be further segmented into

- "Low Quality Questions"
- "Low Quality Answers".

I had to stare hard at an "answer" before I realized it was actually a question.

It would make reviewing faster because you don't have to switch sentiments whenever the UI switches between showing you a question and showing you an answer.

Just sayin'.

Comment: Part of me thinks this is an unnecessarily fine distinction, but on the other hand, it would help reduce confusion for those answers that are low quality precisely because they're actually questions posted in the wrong place.

Comment: @PopularDemand My thinking is that questions and answers have slightly different criteria for being "low quality". If you have to constantly switch criteria in your head, you work slower.

Comment: I think it is better if there is some kind of visual indicator to indicate it is a question or answer for Low Quality category and for Suggested Edit category. Currently, we have to scroll down near the end of the post to see "answered XXX" or "asked XXX".

Comment: @nhahtdh There kind of is, but they should be physically separated nonetheless, so one can work the queue faster.

Comment: Please retain Low Quality Both as well, or a visual indicator....

Comment: Another reason for this is that you cannot usefully review questions once you're out of close votes. Only reviewing answers works though, and this would be one possible way to get that.

Answer (score 48):

#### Voting Up or Down is Missing

Under the old system, you could vote posts up or down while reviewing them. Since voting is one of the metrics tracked for the Reviewer badge, why is this ability not present in the new review interface?

Comment: I was definitely looking for this ability as well.  It feels odd to have to click through to vote ...

Comment: @CodeGnome: Please see http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/140405/why-is-voting-removed-from-new-review-system

Comment: See my answer to Somnath's question ^^^

Comment: @Shog9, as I understand your objection to voting in that post, it seems to be b/c you can't see the other answers, but that's *another* one of the problems w/ the new system, IMO! You *should* be able to see the other answers to judge the contribution of the one in question.

Answer (score 45):

I liked the bits where it showed progress towards badges i.e.

1. Copy Editor
2. Electorate

I find stuff like that quite motivating (sadly). I notice they are now missing. Can they be  reincluded or put somewhere else.

Apologies if I've missed them

Comment: Figuring out where to put these - but they're coming back.

Comment: Brilliant. I can continue to unhealthily obsess about them.

Answer (score 28):

Few comments:

- Can the confirmation for delete please be removed? If not, provide an option. It's the `/review` route. I know a lot will be up for deletion. Having a confirmation is really annoying. At least skip the confirmation for Moderators
- It would be great if all answers were visible, below the question. Having that helps to know whether it should be moved to a comment or deleted altogether
- <s>After approving/rejecting a suggested edit, the other button ( approve/reject) still remains.</s> **Fixed**
- Also, why aren't the voting arrows present on the posts? :/

Comment: +1 on the voting arrows

Comment: You must construct additional voting arrows

Comment: @Sathya: Please see http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/140405/why-is-voting-removed-from-new-review-system

Comment: It's supposed to be annoying. Well, not so much *annoying* as simply a bit *labor-intensive*. Deletion isn't a trivial matter, and moderator deletion can't be reversed by the community - giving you an extra second or two to reconsider is worthwhile. Also, see my answer to Somnath's question.

Answer (score 28):

In the old review-process I could restrict reviews to the tags I understand. In the new review I am supposed to give comments to things I do not understand.

Thus, I would like to have my tags back!

---

For clarification, these work in the old process:

- https://stackoverflow.com/review/late-answers?tag=perl
- https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-questions?tag=perl
- https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-answers?tag=perl

These do not work in the new process:

- https://stackoverflow.com/review-beta/close?tag=perl
- https://stackoverflow.com/review-beta/suggested-edits?tag=perl
- https://stackoverflow.com/review-beta/low-quality-posts?tag=perl

Comment: This was the first thing I noticed. I tend to limit my reviewing _mostly_ to my areas of specific expertise, where I'm most likely to be able to locate duplicate questions, etc.

Comment: This isn't so much a problem when reviewing for writing quality, but it's certainly a major issue when trying to determine whether a post is on-topic or not, and whether it should be closed or migrated. I want tags back too!

Comment: +10 if I could.

Comment: I would love to have this feature. Or at least having the tags at the _very top_ of the question, so that they are visible at first glance.

Answer (score 28):

Users are locked out of reviewing *Close Votes* when they run out of close votes for the day.

Consequently, the [Top Reviewers](https://stackoverflow.com/review-beta/close/stats) each day are the users with the greatest "do not close"-vote to "close"-vote ratio, because they are able to accumulate the most reviews before being locked out. These users also have an advantage in the all time Top Reviewers list -- I took an early lead, but lost it and continue to fall further behind because I cast fewer "do not close" votes than certain other users.

This current design will skew votes towards "do not close", or at least encourage users to select "not sure" instead of "close" to avoid getting locked out. Instead, "close", "do not close" and "edit" should all count towards a daily review limit.

(Why am I including "edit"? It's good to encourage edits, but once we include "do not close", having a larger number of "edit"s would be the only way to get an advantage and would be the new factor determining the daily Top Reviewers. This would lead to a lot of frivolous edits bumping questions that should actually be closed.)

After that, consider *removing* the daily Top Reviewers list. It will be a lot less interesting once everybody's tied at a shared cap.

Comment: "Not Sure" really shouldn't be counting as a review - if you can drive yourself to the top of the leaderboard by *abstaining* then that's a bug. But yeah, "Don't Close" should be limited also.

Comment: @Shog9 You're right, it doesn't count as a review. I just meant that users shouldn't be encouraged to press it when they actually believe that "Close" is appropriate.

Comment: I'd be thrilled if this could be changed before my close:do not close ratio causes me to lose my (slightly unfairly-earned) position at the top of the leaderboard[.](http://i.stack.imgur.com/L3QGm.png)

Answer (score 24):

Awesome, glad to see you guys aren't slacking.  SO's a great site now and will get even better.  I frequent the `review` tab a lot, but my rep's < 2000, so I can't access any of those tasks.  Can you offer the beta only to those who can access it?  Currently, I'm seeing this every time I click `review`.

Comment: You can see the normal review pages linked at the bottom of that page.

Comment: I'm fully aware of that.  I don't like needing to click through twice.  
Alert me once, then let me be, since I can't do anything about it.

Comment: Cool, cool -  just making sure you saw that.

Comment: I agree with @SomeKittens. And I guess I understand why you might want only established users to be able to edit posts. But as someone who constantly edits everything I read, I am going to feel soooo left out.

Comment: Yes, they are __down there__. That's part of the point (as I tried to state downvotedly, earlier). That is kind of annoying. We cant to nothing with that new review stuff that jumps repeatedly to our attention.

Comment: +1, I feel it is important for users < 2000 to at least be able to contribute and suggest edits, otherwise how does the suggested edits queue get filled up?

Answer (score 16):

Some of questions raised due to new review system?

1. How/Does/Where review stats going to be displayed.
2. How new review system will affect the review stats and it's parameters? Why not to show all parameters done in review stats?
   [image]
3. How/where the badge progress on review page(Copy Editor, Electorate) will be shown?
   [image]
4. If we click on Not Sure in reviewing low quality posts, then will those be counted in reviewed posts.
5. Does First answers and First questions are not required to review according to review system?
   [image]
6. Why not given close option for low quality posts? Does only answers shown in low quality posts?
7. Why can't we vote on posts according to new system during review?
   [image]

Comment: #5. They mentioned that first answers and first questions will be added to the new system at a later date.

Comment: And along with that what about late answers given by new users?

Comment: Same thing.  If you look on the [review page](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/review/), it's listed at the bottom under the "Review Lists (old)" header.  "These will soon be moved to the new beta Review Task system"

Comment: Voting in the close, edit, or low-quality queues doesn't make a lot of sense. You're not being asked to rate the question or rank the answers; you're deciding whether a given question doesn't belong, a given edit is helpful, or a given post is of such poor quality that it should be removed entirely. There is a link to the full question though, if you decide to take an interest in it beyond the scope of the queue.

Comment: We will be bringing back badge progress in some form.

Answer (score 15):

I ran into a problem with this today.  I noticed a poor edit suggestion and went to just improve the post and do it right.  I went in, edited the post, submitted it, and I was moved on to the next suggestion.  I went to the thread with the actual post (thanks to the browser history) to review the question and I noticed that my edits didn't take effect.  I went in from the post itself (rather than the new review queue) and re-made my edits.  I was given an error that the title already existed.

Apparently if there is an error making an edit in the queue it just swallows the error, displays nothing to the user, and moves on giving the impression that it worked even if it didn't.

A few unrelated comments:

- I also miss not having the number of approve/reject votes displayed, or the reject reasons displayed, as on the old permanent edit suggestion page.  It also doesn't list the approval/suggestion stats or recent approvals/suggestions (which is less useful than reject reasons, but still useful).
- If you hit 'not sure' for an edit and then go back to it it says you've already voted and can't vote again.  While I can understand approve/reject votes being locked, and it's nice to not have something I've "not sure-ed" show up again in the queue, I would like to change my vote.  This was prompted by a mis-click when I meant to reject a suggested edit.
- When you run out of votes it would be nice of the approve/reject buttons just went away, and there was some indication at the top of the page so that I don't spend time looking through questions that I can't vote on.

Comment: Could you provide a link to the post you had issues with.  I can see several edits from you on various posts.

Comment: @GeoffDalgas I looked through my edits and I wasn't able to find it, sorry.

Comment: @GeoffDalgas I encountered the same problem. I cannot find it in my history either. (on SO)

Comment: I think we found this issue and fixed it - it will be rolling out with the next build.  See here:  http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/139821/where-did-my-improvement-go

Comment: You can now go back and change things you clicked "Not Sure" on

Answer (score 14):

Sub-[feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request)

Navigating the close menu for dupes is annoying. It AJAX requests every time you proceed to the next stage for dupes, and the other close reasons involve two clicks and a wait. Not that big an issue--but it disrupts the flow of the thing, especially for dupes.

The feature request is as follows:

For all options *but* dupe: just select the close reason beforehand so we can click "close" and be done with it.

For dupe, open the close menu at the point where you choose which question to make it a duplicate of. Even better, do this:

[image]

Enable the "duplicate" buttons only if the user has looked at the respective tabs.

Comment: This might make sense; I think [this suggestion has legs](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/138316/improve-ui-flow-for-close-as-duplicate), and could be integrated into both the normal question UI and the /review UI. We're gonna defer this for the time being, but will consider it after the rest of /review is ironed out.

Comment: Tweak suggestion to sub-FR: don't put the "Duplicate 1," "Duplicate 2," &c. buttons on the header bar. Instead, put them inside the duplicate tabs, in the sidebar underneath "link." That will reduce the number of clicks needed to agree with an existing suggested dupe from a whopping __four__ down to one, encourage people to actually verify that dupe suggestions are correct and prevent confused users from agreeing with dupe suggestions blindly. Also, the way the mockup is drawn, the "Duplicate 1" and "Duplicate 2" buttons kick the "Close" button out of its usual spot, which could be confusing.

Answer (score 14):

One thing I *don't* like about the new suggested edit list is that it's no longer a list.

It used to show a list of up to 30 suggested edits, which made it easy to quickly scroll through them looking for things I actually know something about.

The new list shows me just *one* suggested edit, and I have to explicitly skip it (by clicking "Not Sure") before I can see another. It makes reviewing a lot of suggested edits much more awkward.

<strike>An unrelated thought: Should there be an option to show suggested edits tagged with my favorite tags, or to push them to the top of the list? Those are the edits I'm much more likely to be able to judge.</strike> *Posted separately [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/140021/167210)*.

Comment: +100. I really miss the list view. It made it *much* easier to locate the questions I am not qualified to review and skip the rest. Having to review the items one by one is much more time consuming.

Comment: Ugh.. that should have been "questions I *am* qualified to review and skip the rest". Trying to do too many things at once ;-)

Comment: @Leigh: Sounds interesting the other way, though. 8-)}

Comment: Haha. It sounds like "the old layout made it easier for me to do .. absolutely nothing with pending edits" ;)

Comment: I initially agreed with your view, but after a few hours use I got to like the new layout more.

Comment: So far it still feels a bit tedious and awkward to me :/ Having to navigate through every item is much more time consuming than skimming a list IMO.

Comment: It also looks to me like you end up reviewing the exact same list as someone else in the same order: most of my suggested edit reviews this morning were also reviewed by the same other user, ditto my reviews yesterday too.

Answer (score 13):

The Review - close votes section is heavily gimped - I can no longer sort/filter by number of close votes or close reasons.

Please, please get this on the new tasks.

Answer (score 12):

What about the possibility of waiving the 2k reputation requirement for users who have earned the [Marshal](https://stackoverflow.com/badges/1298) and/or [Reviewer](https://stackoverflow.com/badges/1478) badge? I realize this is a small percentage of users, but I'd hate to see reviewing be taken away from those of us who have put in a lot of time on the old reviewing system, and who are still working to achieve the 2k goal.

Comment: This makes no sense at all for some queues - if you can't reasonably take any action in the queue, giving you access to it doesn't accomplish much. Long-term, I would like to gate access to certain privileges based on your demonstrated ability to make use of it, but that's a separate project. 2K won't necessarily be the rep limit for all future queues, but access will continue to be based on the privileges needed to handle at least *some* of the tasks involved.

Answer (score 12):

We can add comments inline now, why can't we have inline:

- Voting
- Editing
- Flagging
- 10k/mod "edit tags"-ing

[image]

Comment: +100, inline flagging. For the love of all things holy inline flagging.

Comment: These queues are not intended to replace the full question and answers page. You also can't post answers, share with your social media accounts, start bounties, view related questions, etc... There's a link to the question, if you want to take an interest in it beyond the scope of the concern raised in the queue.

Comment: @Shog9: it makes it difficult to flag, which means I'll be *less likely to flag*. I have to leave the workflow to flag, which slows me down, and the new system is already a bit slower for me (good? bad? don't know).

Comment: @sixlettervariables if you're encountering a lot of items that *need* to be flagged (as opposed to an action directly available in the queue ) then you should let us know. The intention of these queues is to give you the tools to handle problems directly; if that's not working then we may need to make adjustments.

Comment: @Shog9: I see it a lot in the Low Quality queue.

Comment: @six: can you be specific? Collect a few, identify the flags that would be necessary, and post a new discussion here on MSO linking to them.

Answer (score 12):

May "Not Sure" be replaced with "Next"?

If I want to pass to the next post is not only because I am not sure, but also, e.g., because I am reviewing low quality posts, and I am shown a question that I would vote to close, but I cannot because I have already voted to close all the questions I could.

Answer (score 12):

#### Proposed Edits on Accepted Answers

It should be *much* more obvious (color coding? different border? clown cars and sirens?) when a proposed edit modifies an accepted answer. The tiny "accepted **yes**" on the right-hand side doesn't really leap out; you have to make a conscious decision to check for it each time.

Comment: +1, they could color the vote box like normal, which would help "see" this.

Answer (score 10):

There are actions I want to take on some posts but can't within the review interface, such as flagging or adding a comment (though this is allowed for low-quality posts), and I end up having to open the post separately to do so.  Can you add more choices so that this isn't necessary?  For example, old questions that should be closed but may not get enough close votes or should be migrated to a site not listed in the close dialog [may be better handled by adding a moderator flag](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/3154/how-should-my-flagging-change-when-i-gain-the-ability-to-vote-to-close/3155#3155).

Comment: These queues are not intended to replace the full question and answers page. There's a link to the question, if you want to take an interest in it beyond the scope of the concern raised in the queue. Migration to sites not in the close dialog *should* be fairly rare - an exceptional action.

Answer (score 9):

In a lot of cases I get an answer that's recommended for deletion, but often the question (and any other answers are crappy too). At the moment we lack a lot of context, because we can only see one answer and the question it was given on.

So I'd like an easier way to simply delete or close the question too, without having to open it on a new tab, delete the question, then go back and delete the answer (even though its already deleted).

It might be useful to add a check to see if any other posts on the same question are somewhere in the queue and if so, add them to the screen like the question is at the bottom.

Comment: If the question looks suspect, I recommend breaking out of the queue and handling it directly from the question page.

Comment: That's what I've been doing so far, but it just slows down the process somewhat. But I get that if you're trying to trim down the info, showing everything wouldn't mix well with that

Answer (score 9):

This is both fantastic and marvelous.

Can we have keyboard shortcuts for taking action? It would be lovely.

Say a for accept, r for reject, n for not sure, i for improve.

Comment: +1 for keyboard shortcuts. [Balpha did suggest](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/102769/keyboard-shortcuts-phase-one#comment384148_137252) he will look into adding the keyboard shortcuts for the newer review queue. I guess he can start looking into this now.

Comment: You might as well build in the boilerplate pro-forma comments, so I can leave a comment before I delete/convert/close

Answer (score 9):

*(I had posted this as an addendum to [another answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/139816/167210), but I thought it should be separate.)*

I'd like to have an option to show suggested edits tagged with my favorite tags, or to push them to the top of the list (or, if there is no list, to give them some preference). Those are the edits I'm much more likely to be able to judge.

Answer (score 7):

Under "Review Low Quality Posts" (under /review-beta), when reviewing an answer, the question is showed below the low quality answer. **I would like to also have the other, competing answers listed.**

If I find a low quality answer which is downvoted I'm much more inclined to vote for deletion if I know that there are other, high quaility answers (perhaps even one marked as accepted).

If the low quality answer is the only one, it's worth spending time on improving it, but if there's already an excellent upvoted, accepted answer in there it's just a waste of time.

Comment: I'm not sure if the feature was there yesterday, but today if you look to the right of the Answer under review, there's a "link" that opens a second tab of the browser on Question + Answers.  I agree that it's useful to see the competing answers in some cases, just as you outline.

Comment: I didn't notice the link until now, so I don't know if it was present yesterday. Anyways, I don't think that's enough. I want to see the answers without having to open any new tab/window.

Comment: What you can see without opening the new tab is whether the question has an accepted answer, though you have to scroll down to the question to see that (as opposed to seeing whether the answer under review itself is accepted).   I'm thinking that ideally most answers under review should be judged on their own merits, though I agree with the case you mention (an answer wrong enough that required editing changes its character, but a competing answer is already correct; why bother?).

Comment: We're working on making sure there's a clearly visible link to the full question page on every review item. The purpose of /review is not to duplicate the full question page functionality on every queue, but it is important that you're able to "break out" of the review task and perform other actions on questions where you take an interest beyond the question posed by the queue.

Answer (score 7):

The interface lagged while I was trying to submit an edit from the *Close Votes* review page. The submit button appeared to be disabled after the first submission, but I think I pressed enter multiple times.

It looks like the client let me send the same edit multiple times, and the server accepted them all without collapsing it to a single edit:

> [image: revisions]

Answer (score 6):

In the Close Votes queue, I would really appreciate the ability to see the answers that have been posted to a question without having to click through to the question. A link ("View Answers") that would unfold the answers below the question would be ideal.

Like others here, I don't always have total confidence in my ability to identify duplicate questions about unfamiliar topics. On Stack Overflow, sometimes a question will concern an error that could have several different explanations, and one needs a pretty detailed knowledge of the topic in question to tell which explanation is correct and solves the problem. In that case, two questions could *look* like duplicates, but actually have completely different solutions, and a close vote would not be appropriate.

However, if the two questions have *also* generated very similar answers, and there's some indication that those answers were correct, then the chance of erroneous closure is lower and a close vote is warranted.

As an aside, I'd second other calls for the ability to filter by (at a minimum) tag and close vote type. With that in place, I think this will be a *vastly* more useful interface for reviewing questions with close votes/flags than the old flag interface. Thank you all for working on this!

Comment: I'd almost say that I just want the review page to render the whole question page and simply highlight the offending post. At least that way I get to see the whole picture without needless navigation

Comment: @IvoFlipse, I agree -- that's a viable alternative too, and perhaps it's the best one, since it might be easier to implement! But I think there's a case to be made that hiding the answers until they're wanted reduces clutter.

Comment: They could change the sorting to have the relevant post(s) be at the top of the answers, that would just require a custom sorting

Comment: The UI for this is... pretty tricky. We might come back to this later, particularly for the duplicate case... But for now, we're working on making sure there's a clearly visible link to the full question page on every review item so that you're able to "break out" of the review task and perform other actions on questions where you take an interest beyond the question posed by the queue.

Answer (score 6):

If you don't have enough rep, the page just kind of...doesn't work. It's not immediately clear why I can't perform any of these tasks.

As a 500 Stack Overflow rep user, I see this:

[image]

Ideally, there could at least be something explaining the requirements (and that I don't meet them) for each task I don't qualify for.

So apparently it does say you need at least 2k reputation to review suggested edits. Maybe make that text red (when I don't have enough rep) to draw attention. I literally did not see that when looking over the page.

Comment: The message "You need at least 2k reputation to review Low Quality Posts" is only displayed if you're being locked out for that reason. However, this isn't clear; it just looks like it's a standard part of the description. It would help if the text were emphasized by being red or bold or something.

Comment: @JeremyBanks hah, I didn't even notice that at all. Maybe make the text red.

Comment: That's my problem with this feature, too. But I can't access any of the new, only statistics. And it is written in question part here that you need 2K, 2K and 3K atm.

Comment: The 2k requirement to ACT ON (detected) low quality posts is reasonable.  But, it was one of the things that I used to browse periodically, both to flag non-answers as non-answers, but also to make edit suggestions of things I knew I was capable of describing more accurately or that I knew I could state more clearly what the person was trying to say.  Is it possible that the "old" review system remain present for those users (like me) that can make use of just browsing the "low quality" questions/answers?

Answer (score 6):

This new system has many advantages over the old one, I believe that the only thing I really (but really!) miss is the ability to sort by tag, and some sort of relevance.

A couple of observations, though:

In the low-quality posts section, when presented with a short answer, the problem may not so much be the answer, but the question. It would be useful to have a simple way to work on the question, for instance voting to close it.

I was presented with something like 75% (if not more) of really old answers to equally old questions, where most of them already had accepted answers. Do we really have to wade through tens of thousands of old answers that the community has already relegated to the bottom of the pages by not voting for them? I am all for cleaning up stuff, but this is a bit too much even for me.

A suggestion could be to order the answers presented for review so answers with no votes and for which there is another, accepted answer are presented last in the queue. Especially if there has been no activity on the question for several months.

Similarly, in the close votes section, I was presented with a long series of questions on subjects that I didn't really feel an expert in (the lack of tag filtering again) and which were quite old (nearly a year). Feels a bit strange to be asked to spend time and effort on so many old and forgotten (many didn't show any activity for the last 10 months or so) questions where I don't really feel I have the insight to, for instance, remove a close vote.

Being able to up- and down vote these old questions would be a nice compromise. I'd feel more at ease just voting for a question in a field where I don't feel expert enough to decide whether it should be closed or not.

Lastly, the wording of the close reasons is slightly confusing, if not downright off-putting. Often a question is just a bad question according to the site's standards and expectations (that questions should show some self effort, be researched, etc.). In several occasions "Not a real question" is not correct - they *are* real questions, just not good ones.

In the case of a question that has lingered for months, asked by a user with a rep in the single digits, even if one leaves a polite comment, chances are that nothing will happen. There should be a simple and accepted way to close these questions for what they are, not for some bogus reason (too localized, narq, etc.).

Answer (score 5):

Found a slight quirk.

When a question has a close vote on it, the duplicate is already closed and you vote to close as a duplicate as is suggested by `/review` you get this error:

[image]

As is the case with [this question](https://superuser.com/review-beta/close/8660) the most likely offender is going to be in the form of migrated cross-site duplicates getting closed out and people vote to close different questions as a duplicate with one "winning" the close and the other being left with close votes.

Do these type of duplicate questions need to be hidden from `/review`?

Answer (score 5):

Under the "Close vote" section, it would be nice to have a smaller "reason selection" dialog pop up closer to the top of the screen instead of having the normal VtC dialog appear when `Close` is selected.  Having to respond to the normal one interrupts the workflow.

It might be nice to do away with the normal VtC dialog all together when reviewers were simply assenting to the already selected close reason, but not making it so convenient that it was possible to accidentally click through.

Comment: Our philosophy with the design of the review UI has been to keep it fairly simple and avoid unnecessarily prejudicing you in favor of a particular action. Showing the existing close reasons (yes, there can be multiple) already heavily suggests that the question *should* be closed for one of them, but forcing you to select from the full list reinforces your role in deciding if and how the questions should be closed. That said, for extra-complicated decisions like duplicate-closing, there's definitely room for improvement; see also: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/138316

Answer (score 5):

I like this so far. However, while looking at the `Low quality posts` section, I had issues with it. The only options to choose from are `Looks good`, `Edit`, `Recommend deletion`, and `Not sure`.

What does `Recommend Deletion` do? Does it make a flag or something? I wouldn't mind having the flagging option somewhere on this page, I feel it's sometimes necessary. I may want to flag it as "Not an answer" sometimes, or point out advertisement.

Comment: Bear in mind these "low quality posts" have already been flagged, by algorithmic criteria.  Deletion is a more extreme sanction than downvoting, or (in the case of questions) closing.  Perhaps you could describe what flags would be useful in reviewing these.

Comment: @hardmath I added a few examples. I would also want to know what Recommend Deletion does though. It doesnt create a flag.

Comment: I believe I read somewhere that "recommending deletion" only pushes the post up in one of the queues so it's more likely that someone who _can_ cast delete votes will see it and possibly vote.  No guarantees that it will be voted on though.

Comment: Recommend Deletion prioritizes deletion of the post. Right now, that just means pushing it up in the queue for folks who *can* delete it; in the future, it may do more. We're watching carefully to see how it's used... FWIW: "not an answer" flags effectively *meant* deletion in most cases - if a moderator responded (instead of three 20K users) they could convert to a comment, but unless you're flagging for bogus reasons, that not-an-answer is gonna go away. You should take both of them seriously for that reason.

Answer (score 5):

**Current behavior:**

http://pasteshack.net/images/517641001342191535.png

**Reproduction:**

1. Run out of delete votes.
2. Try to delete yet another post.
3. Get the above error, trying to delete from the question page itself and note I ran out of votes.
4. Be forced to press Not Sure instead to get rid of it showing up again and again... >_<

**Expected bahavior**:

- **Low Quality Posts:** Replacing "Delete" by "Recommend to Delete" when I ran out of close votes.
- **Close Queue:** Replacing "Close" by either a flag or an appropriate message to stop the user.

Comment: Same goes for "close" in `low quality` once you've ran out of close votes.

Comment: @slhck Questions shouldn't be shown anymore if you've run out of close votes; or the `Close` should become a flagging dialog (*doesn't belong here*) like for users below 3000 rep...

Comment: This has been fixed and deployed to production.

Comment: @GeoffDalgas Not for me. The low quality queue still shows answers and prints an unspecific error message when trying to delete ("*An error occurred when deleting this post. Please try again*"). When viewing the answer via the question topic, the error messages states: "*You've reached the maximum of 30 Deletion votes per day; come back in 7 hours*". This clearly has not been fixed. Super User rev 2012.7.21.3438, low quality queue post #7134.

Answer (score 5):

When you did your 50 daily "Close Votes", the link is "blacked out" and a hint is shown: "You have no more close votes today; come back in 3 hours.".

But if you did your 50 reviews of "Suggested Edits", there is no such message. Not before you click "approve" you will get the "Out of votes - you may only vote 50 times a day." notice. (Especially annoying as there is no notion when to will have some more votes again.)

Answer (score 4):

For the 'close votes' tab, it currently asks the following question:

> Should this question be closed as *[insert close reason here]*?

And then has buttons:

- Close
- Do not Close

Clicking 'Close' opens up the close dialog and invites me to choose a reason. It would be faster for reviewing if clicking 'Close' automatically cast a vote for the reason given, that would save having to open up the dialog, selecting an option from the dropdown menu, and then voting to close again. I feel like this slows down my reviewing stride when I'm reviewing a lot of questions.

Perhaps this could be made quicker with another button, something like this:

> Should this question be closed as *[insert close reason here]*?

- Yes *(automatically votes for reason in question)*
- Close for Other Reason *(opens close dialog)*
- Do not Close

Comment: This can't be done in the case where there are close votes for different close reasons.

Answer (score 4):

I was trying the close votes review and noticed that I could be more effective if I could limit the selection to tags I am familiar with.

Its very hard to to judge duplicates and other stuff correctly if the language/tag is one you are not familiar with.

But it is easy to use and I really like it :)

Comment: I'm seeing a raft of SQL answers in the Low Quality Posts queue, and after a half dozen or so begin to suspect that the selection is skewed by the SQL tag being one that I follow.  Do you follow any tags? (I follow three others, but no hits so far on them.)  At first I was thinking SQL lends itself to brief answers, so that the algorithm for Low Quality Answers was responsible for the skewing.

Comment: @hardmath I was using the close vots system and got ton of php questions. I don't have php in my favorite tags.

Answer (score 4):

- When improving an edit I'd like to be able to easily see what the question looked like before the suggested edit - helpful when improving borderline edits. Even just a link to the original post would be good, but it disappears the moment you hit improve. As far as I can see the only way to make the link to the original edit appear is to cancel the improvement.
- When reviewing edits more feedback on what the other reviewers have decided would be good, especially if they've entered a custom message.

Comment: +1 pr much more to this - On some edits when I have had my attention to the question I see the original could be improved but the newer is much worse

Answer (score 4):

Two improvements that I could see going a long way towards improving editing accuracy:

- Showing if a question/answer is Community Wiki in Suggested Edits
- Allowing editors to see comments made on questions (in Suggested Edits only).

The former allows one to take a double take on whether or not the edit improves the question as a whole, and can relax most fears about the edit being vandalism.

The latter allows for editors to indicate if an edit was made in direct response to remarks in the comments.  I may be hesitant to spring for this, as the OP should update their question, but it can help in certain cases.

Comment: CW status should already be visible. Edits that depend on comments are an edge-case - if you're concerned, use the link to break out into the full question page (we'll be making this a bit more obvious).

Answer (score 4):

The new process seems promising, but I'm concerned it implicitly moves the goal posts for deleting Low Quality Answers.

Under [Jeff Atwood's year-old dictum](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/93606/155839), deletion is for *very* low quality answers, unlikely to be salvageable, embarrassingly bad stuff.

The new process encourages reviewers to click Recommend to Delete if the answer under review would require substantial editing to fix (retyping > 20% of the answer and significantly changing its character) while a competing answer has already gotten it right, one way or another.

This might be intentional and/or a good thing.  I'm just saying it's a change in criteria, and possibly [an unintended consequence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unintended_consequences).  The issue may deserve an airing in its own thread, but I wanted to throw it out here as [it's early days](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/it%27s+early+days).

Comment: This is why "Recommend Deletion" is fairly toothless at the moment - we *really* want to keep a sharp eye on it for a while before making it any more powerful. One would hope the majority of reviewers would abstain from recommending deletion of posts that aren't unsalvabeable garbage, but if folks are too delete-happy then we'll need to account for that.

Comment: Perusing the [Reveiw History](http://stackoverflow.com/review-beta/low-quality-posts/history) some people do in fact seem to want to delete code-only answers which I think is a mistake.

Answer (score 4):

In `/Close Votes`, I'd suggest to add the following functionality to the `Do Not Close` button: if the question gets closed, cast a `reopen` vote automatically.

Comment: We're considering a couple possibilities for what "Do Not Close" will ultimately do.  One option is for it to cast a reopen vote.  Another is for it to cause the close votes to start aging and eventually be deleted.

Comment: @David I like the second option, too. It will help to remove old and answered questions from the reviewing queue in a smart (selective), although hard, way. I think both options could be implemented though, they don't seem to contradict.

Answer (score 4):

The Suggested Edits page does not provide any way to get the context.  For example I was reviewing a Suggested Edit that added a change to run a command in the original answer as root.  To undertand whether that was warranted required reading the original question.

When reviewing Vote to Close questions, you can just click the question to get the context.  This is absent in the Suggested Edits page.

I had to click the user, then activity, then find the question the edit was made to so that I could read the question and answer in context.

Comment: I'd also venture that in the case of a non-accepted, low-quality answer, the other answers are an important part of the context, too. An answer may be low-quality, but if there are one or more good answers, then often it could just be left in peace.

Answer (score 3):

What little I can see looks cool now, but it would be nice if some other folks (for example, 40k users on SO who only have 1.6k rep here) could see it too... :)

Maybe I'm dense but I can't figure out what the row of gravatars after each of the tools represents?

Comment: The row of gravatars are recent reviewers. We're working on UI to make that clearer.

Comment: It has now been enabled on SO.

Comment: @GeoffDalgas w00t!

Answer (score 3):

I'm facing an issue related with the rejection of tag-wiki's:

More than once that I've came across and rejected the same tag wiki.

Seems like my previous rejection wasn't registered or isn't being recognized as "already rejected by me" when prepared for presentation.

**Ps:**
Nice work on this new review system, I'm an even more happy user :)

Answer (score 3):

Can we please have a feature to **Improve** wiki tag edits? (clicking more doesn't add the improve option).

For example, in the edit presented below, the spacing and punctuation aren't very good, but the content is sound, however I wouldn't approve it till it is improved, at the same time I don't want to reject it as its not really invalid:

[image: missing improve option for wiki tag edits]

Also, I think it would also help if under the sections for rejection there was a "Edit doesn't match tag" option, specific to wiki tag edits, as I've seen quite a few edits that don't match (either cause they really don't match or there is a misunderstanding of the tag), and typing a custom reason each time is a bit laborious, but at the same time I don't feel that it falls under "Invalid Edit".

Comment: The `Improve` option is omitted here because it's a tag wiki excerpt, and *you* don't have permission to edit tag wikis yet. What *would* be a nice workflow however (possibly) would be to offer you the `Improve` option, and when clicked, route your improvement into the edit queue.

Comment: @Matt: I'm a 12k user, surely I have the option to edit, or at least suggest an edit? however, adding the improvement to the queue for approval would work quite well.

Comment: Editing tag wikis (without it needing to be reviewed) is a [20k privilege](http://stackoverflow.com/privileges/trusted-user). I agree that it'd be nice for you to be able to *suggest* an improvement though; which is what the second part of my original comment was addressing.

Comment: @Matt: makes sense, though, editing a suggested edit isn't the same as editing the tag directly, as it still require approval.

Comment: Yeah, but what I'd possibly like to see is there being an "Improve" option for <20k's, but instead of it being accepted immediately (like it would for a 20k+ user, because they have tag wiki privileges), is for *your* improvement to be added to the suggested edit queue itself.

Comment: Does that means somebody would review your suggested edit for a suggested edit, and decide if it should be accepted? What happens if it is rejected? Would the original suggested edit still need to be reviewed? It is a not necessary complication.

Comment: @kiamlaluno: i envision it to work exactly like improving suggested q/a edits, it'll remove the original edit, and then be place in the review queue

Comment: But in that case, you can improve a suggested edit if you can edit that post. This would mean that the "improve" button would appear to who can edit every tag wiki (20k users).

Comment: @kiamlaluno: those who can edit directly (ie 20k+ users) would have their improvement applied directly, the rest would go into review like normal tag edits (but both will remove the edit they 'improved'). imo its a bit ridiculous to limit improvement to just 20k+ users, totally defeats the purpose of encouraging involvement.

Comment: This would open up a massive can of worms (ending up with some complicated revision history full of pending edits). If you have the ability to edit the wiki directly, you can do this; otherwise, reject the edit.

Answer (score 3):

Could you please rename "Improve" → "Edit" in the suggested edits? "Improve" and "Approve" are just too similar words.

Just now I *ap*proved an edit that I wanted to *im*prove … and mark it as not helpful.

Comment: Uh, no. And if you make this mistake too often, you might want to take a break from reviewing *edits*... ;-)

Answer (score 3):

While I'm not 100% positive it is a result of this new feature, as one who does not have the authority to edit posts directly, I have noticed a significant decrease in the time it takes for my suggestions to be reviewed. Generally within a few minutes, my suggestions are accepted, whereas a few weeks ago, it could have taken a few hours.

It also appears that the suggested edit queue has been kept very low, which also helps me, since I find it very frustrating to look at a horrible, needs-to-be-edited-now post, but I can't submit an edit because there are too many pending suggestions.

From my perspective, the new system works great!

Comment: I think people are reviewing edits more now. I do believe that was a major goal for this, so it sounds like it's working fabulously

Comment: I'm unsure how much of this is the novelty of a brand new system versus people using it more because of the actual changes.  We'll know after another few weeks.

Answer (score 2):

Does the new system take into account favourite and ignored tags as say the interesting tab does.
The reason I ask is that when reviewing I will often ignore items that are not in my skills as I do not know enough and having to click on these will slow things down and put me off reviewing which is not what the change is meant to do.

If we do go to the new interface could we sort the items giving the favourites first , then other interesting.

Comment: I support this, but is this duplicate? http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/140021/172216

Comment: @Caner Yes I think the link looks a duplicate of this

Answer (score 2):

When relative times are used elsewhere, the full datetime is included as a `title` attribute. This isn't the case for the times in the recent review list, or the "asked"/"answered"/"actives" times beside posts. I'd like it to be included.

Comment: Fix going out soon.

Answer (score 2):

One task I'd like to be able to do is look for old questions and answers that are under review. It was difficult under the old system, but impossible under the new. While not everyone is interested in this sort of drudgery, this clean-up can be quite helpful, given the number of old duplicates and poorly written questions that crop up when trying to search the site.

Some have requested a feature to limit reviews to certain tags. My suggestion would be for an expanded version of this, with various filters that can be applied to reviews: tags, dates, the "Close Votes" and "Close Reasons" from the old review system, flags (user- & auto-flags).

Answer (score 2):

If you take action on a suggested edit which has already been approved/ rejected, you get a popup saying (along the lines of):

> This suggested edit has already been approved. Please visit the post and ...

However, after this, you are still sat on the same edit, albeit with the button you clicked removed.

[image]

What I would expect to happen is the controls being replaced by "Next" and that taking you to the next edit.

Answer (score 2):

**Prioritize flags**

It would be nice to have if there was a way to ***filter out auto generated flags*** or some other way to prioritize flagged things. For example `Low Quality Posts` section has many posts auto-flagged incorrectly. This makes it a bit waste of time to go through all of them. The "contribute something useful" to "spent time" ratio is very low IMO on these.

I guess **user flags** are more likely to be accurate than auto flags so it would be nice if they are somehow prioritized and handled immediately.

Another idea is to also **prioritize recently flagged posts**. I guess in most cases it is much more valuable to immediately handle a recent flag rather then spend time on an 1 month old question.

Also auto-flager could be improved. One idea that comes to my mind is that when a question has many answers that are flagged because of **length** & **content**, those answers could be excluded from auto-flag?

[An example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11113008/in-javascript-how-can-i-use-a-function-parameter-as-the-key-to-an-object) of legit answer with many other legit(but flagged) answers:

[image]

Comment: There's a lot of potential here, but for the time being we'll focus on prioritizing items automatically based on the tags you're active in.

Answer (score 2):

It would be great if an option can be provided to filter the answers/questions for review using specified tags.

I cannot see any more progress towards my gold badges, like Copy Editor, Marshal, Proofreader, etc. It will be handy to have one.

Also in the new review system a reviewer cannot upvote/downvote the answer being reviewed (and flagging).

It seems that classification of flagged questions is very confusing. I.e. the classification should be split into groups according to actions to be taken of the question: delete (not a real question, spam), close, move (not belongs here). 3 options should be sufficient.

Answer (score 1):

Does editing from the close vote review page have to take the user away from the question once the edit is submitted? Sometimes I want to both edit and give my opinion on whether the question should be closed.

Comment: Disagree -- this new behavior is a feature not a bug IMHO!

Comment: Yeah, I saw your answer, and expected a downvote. Why do you consider this behavior to be a positive thing?

Comment: I always thought the old behavior was a huge pain, because when you were through editing, you stayed on the question page, and you lost your place in the list of review tasks. The "back" button wouldn't bring you back to the exact same place you were previously in, and the page wouldn't reflect the edit you just did (IIRC). But generally I can't recall wanting to leave a comment after I edited; if this was something I wanted to do frequently, then I could definitely see where you were coming from.

Comment: Editing implies "Do not close".  From the instructions: "Edit if this question could be improved so that it does not need to be closed"

Comment: Well, sure, the _current_ instructions. This proposal includes changing those instructions as a side effect.

Comment: @PopularDemand I'm confused then...are you suggesting that you want to edit the post and then vote to close?

Comment: Sometimes. Just because a post is closed doesn't mean it ought to look like crap. And there's always that "Not Sure" option, too. If a Haskell question has a possible duplicate and I don't know the first thing about Haskell, I should still be given the option to fix up the grammar without saying "I think this dupe suggestion is incorrect."

Answer (score 1):

I would like a little addition to "looks good"
I have reviewed a few answers where the quality of the discussion on the answer was high enough for me to make it a keeper, even though the answer was perhaps voted down.
Perhaps an "answer is good" vs "answer and comments are important"

Comment: "Answer is wrong" is another "Looks Good" reason. Wrong answers are answers all the same.

Answer (score 1):

Is there any chance of going back to the review list upon saving an edit?

When a <2k user clicks on "More" under suggested edits why not show the pending edits without the option to interact? This would show what your <2k peers are editing and how (learn to edit by example).

Answer (score 1):

Should items that have already been edited show up in this list? I have seen both items that have been edited by >2k users (or edited by <2k and approved) in these lists.  I also have seen items that already have an edit pending.

Shouldnt these items be filtered out so we are not reviewing the already edited?

Comment: Which list are you referring to (low quality, vote to close, suggested edits)?

Comment: Review - First Answers

Answer (score 1):

Comment on review for low quality posts.

This applies to low quality answers only.

As noted in other questions we need to be able to vote on these.

We need to be able to see other answers as the action differs depending on these. If there is another good answer then the shown answer should be deleted. If there are no other good answers then it has to be improved.

Re recommend deletion - under the old system the only way to get answers deleted was to flag for a moderator but flags get "declined - flags should not be used to indicate technical inaccuracies, or an altogether wrong answer" so this is a totally new way of doing things. (although I would also note that according to this [Q&A](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/140062/flag-declined-link-only-answer-subsequently-deleted) the mods might not be correct or consistent here) Thus I think the recommend for deletion really needs a full explanation.

Comment: We also definitely need a way to convert (or recommend to convert) to comment. Many bad answers could be at least half-decent and not entirely irrelevant comments. 

It also seems that at least some bad answers are replies to what is basically a bad question, so the root cause would lie with the question. Some tools to deal with the question could be useful on the page to handle low-quality answers.

Comment: If your threshold for convert to comment is "wouldn't be a completely crap comment", then your bar is too low. If your motivation for converting to a comment is "there are better answers", then you misunderstand the purpose of comments. **Comments are *not* for second-tier answers!** If an answer makes no effort to answer the question, then recommend deletion; if it's complete unintelligible garbage, then recommend deletion. If you just disagree with it, or think it could be better, then move on or edit - converting a lousy answer to a lousy comment helps no one.

Comment: @Shog9 - I am referring to answers that jus ask for more details

Comment: @Mark: realistically, those are only useful as comments early in the life of the question. Later on, it makes more sense to just jump out of the LQ queue and vote to close the question.

Comment: FWIW: I'm not completely against doing some sort of "convert to comment" tool here, but I'd prefer to see a clear need first - and some major roadblocks to it even if it is available.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a [bug](/questions/tagged/bug):

When voting to delete an answer with a 0-score, in that case, [this one](https://superuser.com/questions/203047/running-skype-on-a-400-mhz-machine-with-linux/203050#203050), it says that I voted to delete it in the history.

> [image]

… but it doesn't show on the actual post:

> [image]

The `delete (1)` link is missing here.

Comment: This is allowed *only* in the context of the low-quality queue. It came out that down-voting posts from the old queue purely to allow voting-to-delete was a fairly common pattern - which is kinda missing the point. Users who have vote-to-delete rights on answers will see answers that've already been recommended for deletion in their queue *if* the score is 0 or below, and will thus be able to vote-to-delete them. **Voting to deleting 0-scored answers isn't permitted in any other context.**

Comment: Ah, that was actually one thing I had pointed out earlier in context of the "recommend deletion" confusion. Still it would be nice if the post actually showed `delete (1)` on the normal page just so it doesn't come across as a bug ;)

Answer (score 1):

The algorithm under the `'Low Quality Posts'` retrieve too many items of the `SQL` section in my opinion.

`SQL` question are generally  answered by a few number of characters representing the query, with little comments. All the answers are good, maybe they need more explanation, but that's it.

Maybe a filter by tag for this particular case should be an improvement.

Or mix the length of the post with the reputation of the poster. A 20 characters answer of a 2000+ rep user must be better than a 50 characters answer of a 10 rep user.

Comment: Or, check the other answers. If there are 5 (n>1, really) answers on the same question, and all are "low quality" then it may be because that is the best answer warranted by the question. In this case, I'm all for skipping over these. However, as soon as someone has gone a little above and beyond the rest, then maybe the others should be more critically reviewed.

Comment: We're tweaking this formula a bit, to give a *little* more weight to code. Also, not saying it'd help, but... Folks could stand to use a bit more lower-case in their SQL. Just sayin'...

Comment: My personal convention IS ALL CAPS! SORRY GUYS, SQL IS SO MUCH MORE BEAUTIFUL THAT WAY :p

Answer (score 0):

For the Suggested Edits tab, I don't have the 5K rep needed to access the Suggested Edits queue on my main site (SuperUser). I just see it as always 0 suggested edits needed. I do have more than 2K rep on that site, so the link does show up for me, but why is it there if I can't access the queue?

Answer (score -4):

Completely impractical. Very poor workflow design. Presenting reviews one at a time is just too slow a process. If there really are 58.1k 'close' votes pending, nobody is ever going to get to them all.

You need to present 20/50/100 to a page so people can pick their areas of expertise, and probably let people filter them based on tags etc, in fact let them use the existing search function.

And the vote-to-close process needs to be streamlined. For example if you agree with a prior 'exact duplicate' you shouldn't have to go through all the same rigmarole with about 5 mouse clicks.

I would also reconsider the wording of 'not sure'. I am often *extremely* sure that I don't have a view about specific reviews. How about 'don't care' or just 'next'? But with the change above the issue becomes moot.

Comment: I think "*Completely impractical*" is excessive hyperbole.  Also, the vote-to-close aspect has already been mentioned [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/139607/168428).

Comment: @jadarnel27 You are welcome to your opinion; this is mine, and there is no hyperbole in it whatsoever. Please explain how this system improves the chances of dealing with 58.1k votes to close. And then please explain why it is illegitimate to state things that are present in other responses.

Comment: +1 completely agree. Probably will _not do any_ further reviewing with this system ...

Comment: Disagree; in the old design having to scroll and scroll through question was a pain, I prefer keeping my mouse in place and click and click and click (hopefully [with keyboard shortcuts](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/139638/147333) will be even better)

Comment: It seems to be working quite well for some tasks (the suggested edit queue, for instance) so the new review panel is not "completely impractical"; that's the hyperbole I'm talking about.  There's no need to "throw the baby out with the bath water".  Also, any system for dealing with 58k close votes is going to be daunting - but don't forget that there are "many hands" as well, so to speak.  Re: duplicate response, I just don't think it adds anything on to what ManishEarth already said (and his answer is worded much more constructively).

Comment: The whole idea of this is that, as individual user, you *shouldn't* be trying "to get to them all." You're supposed to be working through a bite-sized piece, and other people will work on other bite-sized pieces. You're definitely entitled to your opinion about the workflow, but I think you're kind of missing the point here. Filtering based on tags might be a good idea, though.

Comment: @Laura I don't find that the 'whole idea of this' is actually stated anywhere. I just find a major paradigm shift that adds usability problems and significantly reduces my capability to execute the function concerned.

Comment: @jadarnel27 It is competely impractical for me and at least one other commenter. That is not hyperbole, it is fact. There are already over fifty responses to this question, and I hope there will be many more. I have not read them all: any expectation to the contrary is misplaced. Note that if the proposed redesign was applied to these responses it would make the task of reading them all bfore posting even more Herculean.

Comment: I will add that the vote to delete this post reflects extremely poorly on the voter concerned. This is supposed to be a community discussion where we have been invited to post our opinions. It is not a technical question where there are correct and incorrect answers.

Comment: @EJP You're right; perhaps the introduction to these changes could have more explicitly stated the goal. Typically, the way things work here, though, is that we beta test new features on SO and maybe SF/SU, gather feedback, tweak as necessary, then roll out the feature network-wide. Once it's available across the network, if it's a major change, there will usually be a blog post about it. We can work on better describing our goals when we announce things on meta.

Comment: @EJP Note, however, the first sentence of the announcement: "We are currently soliciting feedback for **an improved version** of /review..." The /review feature has been around for a while; it's just getting an upgrade. I think we assumed that people were already familiar with the goal of /review since some version of it has existed for quite some time, but like I said, we can work on being clearer in the future.

Comment: @Laura I commented on the upgrade, not the feature. Presenting me with an arbitrary sequence of reviews to process until I get sick of it isn't a rational strategy. You should allow me to *choose.*

Comment: I disagree with most of this; the goal has *never* been to have one person reviewing every single item in a queue this size - that's a recipe for burnout. However, I agree that duplicate closing could be streamlined a bit more - we'll be looking at [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/138316/improve-ui-flow-for-close-as-duplicate) after work on /review has progressed further.

Comment: @Shog *That's the point.* That's why I want to be able to filter. When I could see a page full, I could filter. Now I'm given a random sequence. It's not an improvement.