# Where did my improvement go?

Tags: bug, status-completed, suggested-edits, review, improve-edit

I improved [this suggested edit](https://stackoverflow.com/suggested-edits/317034) while working from the new beta review queue. I'm not sure of the exact timing, but I suspect that the edit was approved (at 21:53:02) by the second reviewer while I was editing; going by my activity history, I submitted my edit between 21:51:36 and 21:57:37.

I'm absolutely sure I submitted my edit before 22:16:33 when the question was migrated.

Where did my edit go? It appears neither in the question's history (which is still sitting at revision 2) nor in my activity¹.

¹ 
<sub>I was operating from the new review queue, so when I pressed `Saved Edits`, I was teleported to another suggested edit. I went to my activity page, because I wanted to vote to migrate the question, but it wasn't there. I thought there was a cache effect, so I waited a bit, but when I saw other edits turn up in my activity, I searched the question on the site, saw that there was no trace of my edit, and came to meta to report the bug.</sub>

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's the sequence of events - quite a bit of action here:

```
user1   2012-07-14 21:52:37 /suggested-edit/317034/vote/approve SuggestedEdits/VoteToApproveOrReject 
user2   2012-07-14 21:53:02 /suggested-edit/317034/vote/approve SuggestedEdits/VoteToApproveOrReject 
user2   2012-07-14 21:53:08 /posts/11486918/vote/6  Posts/Vote 
user3   2012-07-14 21:53:19 /posts/11486918/edit-submit/5a6fd42f-a239-464d-9196-3f545df3a603    Posts/EditSubmit 
user4   2012-07-14 22:16:29 /posts/11486918/vote/6  Posts/Vote
```

So the suggested edit was approved prior to your edit submission which requires more substantial edits for it to override the previous approval.  The bug here is that we were silently ignoring the error returned from edits.  The post was then closed and migrated to Super User.

This has been fixed and will be rolled out with the next build.