# Burninate the Meta "Improvements" tag

Tags: discussion, status-completed, meta, meta-tags, burninate-request

The Meta Stack Overflow tag [improvements](/questions/tagged/improvements) is in use on 45 questions.  In the huge majority of them it is being used in the sense of "this is something that should be improved on Stack Exchange" (i.e. redundant alongside [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request)).

I could only find two examples of it used in a more legitimate sense of "Improving an edit" - located [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/95520/allow-improve-for-tag-wiki-edit-suggestions) and [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/139821/where-did-my-improvement-go).  Perhaps these two could be tagged with `improved-edits` or similar instead.

Either way the `improvements` tag seems to add nothing to question.  Burninate it as a meta-meta tag?

Comment: Meta tags on meta? *explodes*

Comment: @BenBrocka - meta-ception :D

Comment: It's downright [metaphysical](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I retagged the two questions that pertained to [suggested-edits](/questions/tagged/suggested-edits)' [improve](/questions/tagged/improve) action.

And then destroyed the tag.

[image: tag burninated]

Comment: +1 for the Burninator dragon-bat-muscle-stick-figure thing.