# Where can I find badge progress for Copy Editor and Electorate on the new review page?

Tags: discussion

On the previous review page, it was possible to see the badge progress for the Copy Editor and Electorate badges in the right-hand column. On the new review page, that information is gone.

Is it possible to find that information somewhere else?

For the Electorate badge I can view my profile page, to see how many questions I have voted on, but how about the number of edits?

Comment: The page is still in beta. Comments/discussion about it should be placed under [this question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/139536/131713). You can upvote [this answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/139645/131713) to show your support for showing badge progress info, but it's probably unnecessary: "you are still making progress. We will add this back to the new review task soon." – Geoff Dalgas♦ [Jul 12 at 20:27](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/139536/new-feature-community-review-tasks-now-in-beta#comment393547_139536)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

We have implemented a new way to see the progress towards the review badges.  Hover your mouse over the progress bar at the top of the page and you will find a breakdown of how close you are to achieving any of the three badges you can earn per review queue.

[image: review badges]

Comment: Does the little vertical bar represent 250/Reviewer?

Comment: Yes, it does - good eye

Comment: Well, the question was about Copy Editor and Electorate... could you add those to the new display as well? (I like the new look)

Comment: They have been added @yoda

Comment: does this still work?