# Where is badge progress indicator in review section?

Tags: discussion, badges, review

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Where can I find badge progress for Copy Editor and Electorate on the new review page?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/140111/where-can-i-find-badge-progress-for-copy-editor-and-electorate-on-the-new-review)

Now its not displaying Badge progress indicator in my review section. where can I find the badge progress for **Copy Editor** and **Civic Duty/Electorate**.

[image]

Comment: I miss that as well. I think this was noted in the original review-beta feedback question but that thread got out of hand.

Comment: Already a "known issue": http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/139645/152859 and http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/139551/152859

Comment: Also noted by Geoff in the comments: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/139536/new-feature-community-review-tasks-now-in-beta#comment393547_139536

Comment: This is an __exact__ duplicate of [Where can I find badge progress for Copy Editor and Electorate on the new review page?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/140111/131713) It's probably better to close as a dupe of New Feature: Community Review Tasks - Now in Beta, though. From the comments there: "you are still making progress. We will add this back to the new review task soon." – Geoff Dalgas♦ Jul 12 at 20:27

Answer (score 2, accepted):

// I found the answer in [this link](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/140130)

it's under (old system for less 2k rep)

```
review->first answer
review->first question
review->late answer
review->low quality
```