# How can I see my badge progress now we have the new review system?

Tags: support, badges, badge-request

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Where is badge progress indicator in review section?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/141109/where-is-badge-progress-indicator-in-review-section)

I used to be able to see how far along I was with a couple of gold badges - Editor and Electorate - but now I can't find that number/% anywhere.

Comment: It's still present on one of the [older review queues](http://stackoverflow.com/review/first-answers).

Answer (score 3):

Go to the [old review lists](https://stackoverflow.com/review/late-answers), you can still see your progress there.