# Bug in new badge progress indicator

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, badge-progress

In the new [badge progress indicator](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/149516/166025), there is some calculation issue. Check the screenshot below with *947* displayed against the *Civic Duty* badge. Am I missing something here or is it a bug?

Edit: If its by design then can't complain but in my opinion if a user has received a badge then it should be removed from the  progress list because there will be no progress on that badge in the future. Specially when the higher level (gold badge - Electorate) is also shown.

[image]

Comment: Regarding your edit - I think it's better to leave it there so you can see all those related badges together in one place. Maybe change the design to show "earned" instead of progress bar and number, but it should be there.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You get the civic duty badge for 300 votes or more. You have however voted 947 times, more than fulfilling the requirements. So this is not a bug but a simple display of information.