# Where is my progress indicator?

Tags: discussion, review, badge-progress

On Friday I was able to see my [review progress](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/149516/74022), now I don't see it.

[image: review screen]

Where did it go? Were restrictions added to when it will be visible?

Comment: +1 Just came here to ask that

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We're playing around with some performance tuning, it'll be back on soon (and your progress is still being tracked, don't worry!).

Comment: I'm too OP of this question. And accept this as an answer. :)

Comment: That was quick - back already