# Tracking badges

Tags: feature-request, badges

The hovering “Badge Progress” SuperDropdown™ in the review pages does a perfect job for a few of them:

[image: Imgur]

Only:

- It's somehow hard to find, and I don't see much reason for editing badges to be mentioned in the *review* section.
- The archaeologist badge seems untrackable.

Related question: [Where can I find badge progress for Copy Editor and Electorate on the new review page?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/140111/where-can-i-find-badge-progress-for-copy-editor-and-electorate-on-the-new-review#comment431613_149516)

Could more of these be made available? Not necessarily in the review pages?