# Hashmark & total progress indicator within review tool

Tags: discussion, review

Within the review tool, there is a progress display which looks like this (for me, today)

[image]

So that you can see what kinds of numbers are (presumably) being used to compute the progress, here's what comes up when I hover over this progress bar:

[image]

I have two questions:

1:  What does this hashmark represent, circled here free-hand:

[image]

2:  The progress bar seems to represent some kind of "total progress", where when at 100% the entire bar will be filled.  Within that there is also a hash mark, #1 above, but what is the total area representing?  The total area I'm talking about is bracketed here:

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For #1, [you're right](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/140111/where-can-i-find-badge-progress-for-copy-editor-and-electorate-on-the-new-review#comment429882_149516):

> Does the little vertical bar represent 250/Reviewer? –Popular Demand
>
> Yes, it does - good eye –Geoff Dalgas♦

(I know that looks self-promotional, but I only remembered that reference at all because I was part of it.)

For #2, you're slightly overthinking the awesomeness of the graph. That bar represents your progress towards Steward — the gold cousin of Custodian and Reviewer — regardless of how much progress you've made. Compare that to the top area of the dropdown, which always shows your progress towards the next member of that family.

[image: progress bar 2 is the portion of progress bar 1 from the start to the vertical bar]

Finally, the bottom part of the dropdown just has some bonus info about other badges.

Comment: Aha! I think I get it now.