# Isn't voting and editing possible from the review queue?

Tags: support, review

I am participating in the review queue for (nearly) the first time, on Stack Overflow. I see that in the upper right hand corner, we can view our badge progress by hovering over the bar, as described [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/140111/where-can-i-find-badge-progress-for-copy-editor-and-electorate-on-the-new-review). This progress includes progress toward Copy Editor and Electorate.

However, this is confusing for me because in the review queue (for Triage) I don't see the ability to vote on posts, or to edit them. I can only comment and vote ("Looks OK", "Requires Editing", etc.).

What am I missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's all explained [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/295650/is-there-a-guide-for-the-triage-queue/295674#295674). The idea of triage is:

> The primary goal of Triage is to quickly sort potentially-problematic posts into categories that can be routed elsewhere...

Voting is possible in some conditions, like if you're the third reviewer to choose **[Looks Good]**.

Read the [post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/295650/is-there-a-guide-for-the-triage-queue/295674#295674) for the full mechanism of the triage queue.

Comment: Ok so voting is sometimes possible, but what about editing?

Comment: you can always click on the link of the post and edit it.

Comment: Oooh, thanks. I was throw off by the lack of an edit link.