# Users exceeding daily maximum 50 close votes

Tags: discussion, vote-to-close

During the review beta, it seems that deleted posts don't count against the daily maximum 50 close votes that may be cast per user.

However, I've noticed users voting up to 80-times, seen here from the beta review close stats:

> [image: close-votes]

How is this cap exceeded to such extent?

Comment: Not sure, but have you checked whether "Do not close" and "Skip" counts towards the number of reviews?

Comment: I rarely select "Do not close"; but I often click "Not sure" to skip which has never counted as a vote.

Comment: I'm pretty sure at least "Do not close" counts.

Comment: This actually has been brought up in the [review beta thread](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/139536/new-feature-community-review-tasks-now-in-beta), but I haven't checked whether they have changed anything to the mechanism.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because there is now a hard limit of 40 review tasks, making this question irrelevant.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Both options "Do Not Close" and "Edit" also contribute to the action count. The option "Not Sure" does not contribute to it. It's basically like a tracker for how many posts you **took action on**. You know, that silly word "actioned" in the Reviewer badge description. Since this doesn't actually keep track of how many posts you've looked at overall, I'm guessing that badge is going to change when the new system goes out of beta.

The same logic is applied to all the review tasks. Anything that's not a "Not Sure" or "Skip" increases your action count.