# What is the business logic behind how many close votes one has?

Tags: support, vote-to-close

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Are there any voting limits?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5212/are-there-any-voting-limits)

What is the business logic behind how many close votes one has? To clarify, I'm not asking for more. I simply don't understand where the current numbers come from and what drive them. To become a more effective member of the SO community it will strongly help me to understand the rationale for deciding these things.

For example, there are currently 55k questions pending close votes. I imagine that the number of close votes was increased from 24 to 50 to cope with the backlog.  Is this really the sweet spot to balance any one user having too much power against reviews being processed effectively?

Perhaps not but I certainly am in no position to suggest it be increased not understanding how the current number is determined, especially when the number of close votes I cast today before being informed I had no more is, in fact, a prime number.

Comment: You mean, why are close votes limited to a specific amount? Most likely the same reason as most limit: to stop a single users from having too much of an influence on the site.

Comment: I understand that, I was wondering the logic that determines how many votes an individual gets.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5212/are-there-any-voting-limits - Logic = a fixed number (12) open/close votes per day. I have never reached this limit, even though I'm an active user, so this limit seems OK.

Comment: @RobW - I've cast > 12 today, so that info must be obsolete.

Comment: Actually, I think that's obsolete. It's up to 50 on SO, not sure the exact formula, looking....

Comment: @PopularDemand You're correct with regards to the amount: [*"2011-04-14: Daily number of close votes on all Stack Exchange sites have been increased from 12 to 24, and 50 on Stack Overflow."*](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/59445/recent-feature-changes-to-stack-exchange) So I would guess the exact amount is rather arbitrary (based on site size/traffic)

Comment: Actually I think that _is_ the answer, @Bart. All SO users who have close vote privileges get 50 close votes/day; all users of other sites who have close vote privileges get 24 per day. (Therefore, not a true dupe, this is completely answered by Jeff [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/87291/131713).)

Comment: I've edited the CW FAQ with the correct information. My previous point still stands though: The current vote limit is OK, and does not need to be increased (you didn't explicitly state it in your question, but other than wanting more close votes, I see no reason for the question to be posted).

Comment: @Bart - I've cast 59 today per the info under "review" link.

Comment: @djechlin That might have to do with questions being deleted? I am not entirely sure on this.

Comment: Now that I (and apparently Rob W as well) edited the FAQ, this can safely be closed as a dupe.

Comment: @djechlin where'd you come up with the number 59? Was it the close vote review queue? If so, see [Users exceeding daily maximum 50 close votes](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/140193/users-exceeding-daily-maximum-50-close-votes)

Comment: @djechlin [Downvotes are different on meta](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/faq#vote-differences)

Comment: @Servy - thanks.  Essentially yes, I should take more onus to delineate a feature request or proposal from actually not knowing what's going on.  Will review meta FAQ for anything else unintuitive.

Comment: @Servy that's true, but I don't think it's relevant in this case. The OP is asking for a piece of factual information, not opinions or discussion. And the FAQ wasn't even accurate at the time the question was asked. I, for one, am confused by the heavy downvoting.

Comment: @PopularDemand Well, he did edit the post after a while to change it from asking how many there are to requesting that the number be increased.

Comment: What? I didn't even see that edit! Sorry, @Servy.

Comment: @Servy - wait what?  I definitely didn't and don't see anything as such in the edit logs.  I started by just asking which at least one person thought implied I wanted an increase, then revised to explicitly say I wasn't.

Comment: @djechlin In any case, don't worry too much about downvotes on Meta. They come rather more freely here. And your initial revision was not all that clear, possibly inviting some (mistaken?) downvotes. You've gotten some info now. As for the exact reasoning behind the exact amounts, I guess we'll just have to see if someone in the know answers. I've modified your question so it reads a bit better (IMHO).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

All users with the vote-to-close privilege have the same amount of votes available to them on a daily basis.

That is, 24 votes on all sites except for Stack Overflow where the number is 50. [I quote](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/59445/recent-feature-changes-to-stack-exchange):

> *2011-04-14: Daily number of close votes on all Stack Exchange sites
>   have been increased from 12 to 24, and 50 on Stack Overflow.*

The higher amount for Stack Overflow is most likely due to the comparatively bigger size and higher traffic for Stack Overflow.

And the fact that a limit is there is most likely to prevent a single user from having too much of an influence on the site. Whether or not these exact amounts hit a certain sweet spot I don't know. I simply don't have the figures on that.