# Edit Awaiting Approval from a Peer

Tags: support, edits

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do suggested edits work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/76251/how-do-suggested-edits-work)

After you have edited a post, does it really go to a peer, or does a robot accept the changes (only under certain rules)?

It says this:

`This edit will be visible only to you until it is peer reviewed.`

Because, every time I edit spelling or grammar in a post, it takes a few minutes to approve.

I think this is a support question, but I'm not sure if it is a discussion or a support question.

Comment: @UristMcBobby - isn't that talking about **edit privileges**? I have edit privileges, but can't review other people's edits.

Comment: If you read some of the points in the accepted answer of the question @UristMcBobby links to, you will see they are related to your question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It will be reviewed by a peer indeed. 2 or more usually.

It will end up in a "suggested edit" queue which those of us with enough reputation can see and vote upon. Once an edit is accepted or rejected, you will be able to see who voted on it and what their vote was.

Have a look for example at [this suggested edit of yours](https://stackoverflow.com/suggested-edits/318099) where the users who approved it are clearly visible.

Comment: Wow, ok thanks, never knew that before :)

Answer (score 4):

It always gets routed into the suggested edit queue.

On Stack Overflow, it will stay there until it has received either **2** approvals or rejections, **or** another peer *Improves* your edit. On other Stack Exchange sites, it only takes 1 peer to review.

Once you get [2000 rep](https://stackoverflow.com/privileges/edit), you will be able to edit posts without the need for review.

Normally I think you'll see edits taking longer to be approved, but right now theres [a new review tool out](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/139536/new-feature-community-review-tasks-now-in-beta), which everyone is happy to try out (until the novelty wears off, at least).

Comment: +1 for mentioning the new queue as the reason edits are being approved so fast.  Until recently the queue was almost always over 100 edits and they usually took hours/days to get approved.