# Should questions and answers have distinguishing icons/letters?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, review

### Overview

Slightly suggested in [Feature Community Review Tasks](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/139536/new-feature-community-review-tasks-now-in-beta#comment393641_139570)
for SO Review

I pulled my example from the first questions Review section because I didn't have access to the Answers and Questions review sections which would benefit from this feature.

#### Question:

Should questions and answers have distinguishing icons/letters?

E.G.: While reviewing there is either a Q or an A (or icons denoting such) above/next to the vote count.

[image]

#### Benefits:

- Quickly identify whats what while editing/voting/cleaning up
- Be able to quickly judge based on content without having to take time determining what criteria you should judge by (question or answer).

#### Cons:

*Any suggestions?*

Comment: Distinguishing icons/letters *where*?

Comment: @BoltClock'saUnicorn `above the voting buttons` or if I get what you mean `on SO`

Comment: Is that a question regarding the general presentation or just in Review ?

Comment: @dystroy why not both?

Comment: My eye is tired by too many items. It seems useful for Review as confusion is possible but not for general presentation.

Comment: Can you provide a link to a page, or a screenshot, demonstrating an interface in which it's hard to distinguish questions from answers? I'm not having that problem, myself, on the review pages I've used.

Comment: @dystroy I checked the Review page vs SO again and I have updated the question to be for Review only.

Comment: @MichaelPetrotta Added image.