# Why review low quality answers to locked questions?

Tags: feature-request, answers, review, low-quality-posts, locked-questions

This comes up in the review pane for Review Low Quality Posts:

https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/71833

This is really a "piss poor" answer (quote from the answer) to a not very good question. From the options "Looks Good", "Delete", and "Not Sure", I obviously chose "Delete". But that didn't work, because the question is locked.

Should I then press "Looks Good" instead?

I suggest we filter out posts that cannot be acted upon.

---

Today, when reviewing  some of our [favorite cartoons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/84556/whats-your-favorite-programmer-cartoon) I notice that the "Edit" button is not present on answers to locked questions, but the "Delete" button is. So there obviously is some kind of detection.

Could this perhaps be extended to control the "Delete" button as well? Or to not show these answers at all?

Answer (score 5):

This is a good suggestion, you should add it to the list of suggestions on the Beta Review Page announcement:

[New Feature: Community Review Tasks - Now in Beta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/139536/147645)

Although I wonder why you can't delete low quality answers on locked questions. If the answer is low quality, it shouldn't be there, period.

Comment: Technically we can't do much at all with locked posts - not edit, or upvote, or comment, or add new answers. And definitely not vote to delete. But we can review them.  :-)

Comment: That feedback question has gotten a bit unwieldy.  At this point we're asking people to just start posting normal [feature-request] and [bug] questions.

Comment: @DavidFullerton My bad, thanks for the info.