# For some users, StackOverflow's review page "soliciting feedback" link sends to a page with no questions

Tags: bug, stack-overflow, hyperlinks, review, feedback

When clicking on "review" at the top of my SO page, I'm taken to https://stackoverflow.com/review/.

There, there is a comment

> We're currently soliciting feedback on an improved system for reviewing posts on the site:

And then it sends to the link https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/review, which makes it look like there's no place to really enter feedback. Sure, one can do like I'm doing and ask a new question, but it seems likely to get lost in the noise.

When I paste that URL into a different browser, I see questions.

So, it seems broken that clicking from SO into meta-SO causes this to happen. I'm expecting that there are others like me that get there, think that the link is out of date, and give up thinking the feedback solicitation period is over.

the link at https://stackoverflow.com/review/ should be changed to https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/review?sort=newest to prevent this broken workflow.

EDIT: Here's what I see when I click on https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/review:

[image]

Comment: also note that the 'big bold text' says "You are on the featured tab", but i don't see a featured tab anywhere in that screenshot.  how would i know whether to select one of the items "Questions" "Tags" "Users" "Badges" or "Unanswered"  or instead "Info" "newest" "faq" et al to get where the original link intended me to go?

Answer (score 3):

I think it's meant to send you to the list of questions tagged [review](/questions/tagged/review) - so if you have feedback about the review process, you should search those questions first before asking your question, since there's a good chance someone else has already asked the question you want to ask.

Based on the screen shot you've shown, you're actually at:

https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/review?sort=featured

Try changing the URL to:

https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/review?sort=newest

Or, click on the "newest" tab.

Comment: i did not want to ask a question.  and there are no questions at that location when you get there.  i wanted to see if there was feedback similar to what i would suggest, and comment on it if so, or upvote it, or add my own.  i guess i expected a "discussion" entry where this was happening.  my point is that it is confusing that there is a "link" next to something that says "soliciting feedback", and then not really any real indication that there is any feedback solicitation going on when you get there.

Comment: `... no questions at that location` really? I see a bunch, including this one, [New Review System: Buttons sometimes disapear for closing a question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/140679/new-review-system-buttons-sometimes-disapear-for-closing-a-question), [Why review low quality answers to locked questions?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/140645/why-review-low-quality-answers-to-locked-questions), [Why is voting removed from new review system?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/140405/why-is-voting-removed-from-new-review-system). Lots of dialog, did you click on any?

Comment: it's all well and good that i ended up where i ended up.  i am not so much interested in giving feedback on review at this point as i am interested i helping others who got where i ended up understand that there really is active feedback solicitation going on without having to come to this answer to figure out how to get there.

Comment: Well Like I said, I don't know how you possibly clicked on that link and got to the featured tab by default, unless you had been on the featured tab before. The navigation to get out of where you ended up is not all that complicated...

Comment: That can happen on any site for any tag if there are no featured questions. It may seem broken to you but, sorry, it's not.

Comment: @john.k.doe It clearly says in that screenshot in big, bold letters, "You are on the Featured tab. There are not questions with an active bounty at the moment. Perhaps you'd like to select a different tab?" How hard is that to figure out? There are other questions here about what should happen when you land on an empty featured tab. But really, how many users will have even left Meta on the featured tab and end up there when they click the link?

Comment: @john.k.doe The problem with forcing it to newest is that then you interfere with people's preferences. By explicitly visiting the newest tab, you're changing that user's preference across the site to newest. There are other options such as *votes*, *active*, and *unanswered* which would still show questions and still follow a user's preferences for viewing. You can't just force it on everyone and call it good.

Comment: They're only forced to take another step right now because there are no featured questions. If what they actually wanted *were* featured questions, and there were such questions, your proposal would make them take an extra step, while the default behavior would not.

Comment: YOU are missing the point. This is happening to you, not everyone. You only got to the featured tab because you were there before. People coming to meta.so for the first time (or anybody who *didn't* use the featured tab on their last visit) are not going to land on the featured tab, and are going to see the full list of questions. Get it? I'm sorry if you want to down-vote me because that's not the answer you want to hear, but this is how the navigation works on every single Stack Exchange site. Not too many people seem to find it broken.

Comment: Where's my ignore button? Wow.

Answer (score 2):

Any Stack Exchange site remembers if you visited the [featured](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions?sort=featured) tab, and try to show it also when you visit a tag page. If you see the page for [review](/questions/tagged/review) after having visited the previous link I provided, you will see that message.
The shown message should be clear enough to make users understand there are questions for that tag, but there are not active bounties for those questions.

The provided link could point to https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/review?sort=newest. Although, I see it like a test: If the users are able to resolve the mystery of the hidden questions, then those users can give feedback on the new review system. `;)`