# Beta "Broken" Links Review is "Broken" for facebook.stackoverflow.com

Tags: bug, status-deferred, review, broken-link, facebook.stackoverflow

Though the page is still in beta stage, the connection should at least point properly for posted tagged [facebook](/questions/tagged/facebook). Going to this page returns all posts for Stack Overflow. Unless the intended feature should persuade users to fix all posts regardless of tags?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Strictly-speaking, this review page isn't *even* in beta yet. At some point, it will be integrated into the new [Community Review Dashboard](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/139536/new-feature-community-review-tasks-now-in-beta) and made more widely available - but there's a fair bit of work left to be done twixt now and then.

Suffice to say, there are all sorts of bugs in it now, and you don't really need to report them - the current availability is strictly *for your information only.*

Comment: Any progress on that? I'm awaiting it eagerly...