# New Review System suggestion: allow reviewing users to select by tag

Tags: feature-request, review

The new reviewing system is nice.

But, do you think it would be helpful if a reviewing user could select items to review by topic tag?  That way folks can review stuff they're interested in.

Comment: Totally agree and I believe someone suggested it [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/139536/147645)

Comment: Yeah, continuously pressing "Not sure" because of this can be really tiresome.

Comment: How is it that the "Old System" had filtering but they managed to not see that when deploying the "New System"?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think that being able to select tags would certainly be a good idea.

Also, it would be awesome if the queue could be prioritized  to the tags which I have historically answered questions using that side information as topics I know of. There are a couple of exotic tags of which I'm a historically top answerer, so if I'm volunteering my time reviewing stuff, as a "make better use of resources" type of thing, I should be a person to ask. Also, ideally, the votes to close review could use the yellow background if that question would fall on my Interesting page, just to call my attention.

Comment: Prioritizing your favorite tags would also be helpful.

Answer (score 6):

### ..because hitting "Not sure" sucks.

I do like the new reviewing system but I must admit I feel overwhelmed by the multitude of topics we have to handle to properly judge and correct a given question/answer.

For example:
how do I know if the suggested edit is correct if I don't know the proper syntax of some esoteric language?

It would be useful to have a feature to pick our preferred tags allowing us to review with   more confidence; after all it's better helping to review on our preferred tags rather than do nothing at all.

Answer (score 1):

### Filtering by tag is fundamental

**The problem:** the badge system combined with the *No Action Needed* button potentially creates incentive to blindly accept whatever comes. The result is that too often I see very poorly formulated first questions.

I believe that giving the ability to review questions by tag will channel the question to competent (by field) reviewers, thus improving the quality of the content in the forum (instead of propagating noise).

Finally, it might be useful to automatically map reviews with users that earned the badge which is listed in the first question.

Comment: you can already filter by tag

Comment: In which context, then how?

Comment: In the review queue, next to the name of the queue, there is a link "filter". And you can put tags in there! But nobody knows about it

Comment: Thanks, found it! Can I create a link that I can bookmark?

Comment: On the comment? `http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/140959/new-review-system-suggestion-allow-reviewing-users-to-select-by-tag/176951?noredirect=1#comment-531766`

Comment: No, on the review page with selected tag. I guess however, that it is saved within my profile.

Comment: Yeah normally it should be saved on your profile