# Review not allowing for Filtering

Tags: bug, review

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [New Review System suggestion: allow reviewing users to select by tag](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/140959/new-review-system-suggestion-allow-reviewing-users-to-select-by-tag)

In going through the list of Reviews on [so] and am getting every single First Post of New User ever posted.  I am unable to filter the listing to my actively used tags.

This would be in response to the "New" beta Review system associated with accounts.