# Why do I need 2k rep to review? (new system)

Tags: discussion

Edit after rollback: **Solution was to reload page. I saw only cached version w/o log in.**

I still don't understand why I need >2k or >3k rep to do a review.

My main support for SO lies in editing questions to look more nice (code!) and maybe more clear (text, content) and of course in giving some votes. *Since today I'm not able to do this any longer.*

I was not able to pick a answer to my question from the [main thread for new feature](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/139536), but I fear I just overread it. But I found the [original link](https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-questions?s=1&pagesize=15&filter=all) which still works.

Edit: I'm know about that my edits are only suggestions and that I still can do this with <2k, but since today I have to sort all questions for activity and go through one by one. Old review section pointed more clear where sth. is to do and had been accessible by myself.

Comment: Even though you don't need it anymore, someone else might find the information useful, I rolled back the edit.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> My main support for SO lies in editing questions to look more nice

Well, good news, this change has no bearing on your ability to do that whatsoever.  You can still suggest edits like you used to.  The feature that requires 2000 reputation or higher is the ability to approve *other's* suggested edits via the new system (and of course, you still need 2000 reputation or higher to edit "unassisted" as always).

If you're simply looking for the old review features, they are available at the bottom of the review page (first answers, etc.) for the time being. I'm not honestly sure what the fate of those is going to be with the new system, but it sounds to me like they're going to be rolled into it somewhere. I can't check on SO or MSO, but I believe those should still be accessible to you.

Comment: The old system should be accessible by anyone.

Comment: Usually I try a bit more before I ask a question. Today I didn't. I used this old section at bottom part since the new beta. My problem's source was far away from reality. Do you have a suggest how to deal with it now? Marking your answer as right is right but it is not.

Comment: @ShegitBrahm You certainly don't need to select it if you don't think it answers your question.  I believe it did answer the original one, though, for someone encountering this same problem or misperception in the future.