# Suggested edits on posts with 100+ votes overflows the icon box

Tags: bug, user-interface, suggested-edits

This probably falls along the lines of being as minor as a pluralization bug...

I noticed that the vote count in the upper-left corner isn't being rendered properly.

**It overflows the icon box:**

[image]

Link: https://stackoverflow.com/suggested-edits/335491

I realized that even the 3rd digit overruns the box. So I checked a suggested edit on a post with < 1000 votes and sure enough, it still overflows:

[image]

Link: https://stackoverflow.com/suggested-edits/203560

---

Unlike on the profile pages:

- The font size fails to shrink for +100 posts.
- The icon box fails to expand for +1000 posts.
- The color doesn't change to green with yellow text when the post is an accepted answer.

I didn't notice this before. So was it a recent update that broke it?

Comment: For some reason the `<span>` containing the score has a fixed width of 15 pixels so its background covers only those 15 pixels but as it has no `overflow: hidden;` the text overflowing that width is still visible. The whole Review system went through a [major change recently](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/139536/new-feature-community-review-tasks-now-in-beta) so it's likely they changed CSS while working on that.

Comment: If you see somebody with a big K walking in your direction, please run!

Comment: I find the edit reason ironic on the four-digit post example. ;)

Comment: This looks like it's [meta-tag:status-completed] now. Waiting for a mod to add the tag.