# Cannot access status of suggested edit from profile page

Tags: bug, status-completed, profile-page, suggested-edits

In the latest build, from the list of suggested edit in my profile or other's profile (e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/users/1400768/nhahtdh?tab=activity&sort=suggestions), I can no longer access the details of the suggested edits and whether they are accepted or rejected.

I hope this is a [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) rather than [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign).

> [image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/dbReQ.png]

Comment: Ha, and here I thought I had gone crazy (or perhaps we both have)...

Comment: They also removed the old suggested edit queue - I'm gonna miss that, since it is easier to work with that old queue.

Comment: It looks like the "reviews" items were updated a little bit (and contain a link to both the post and the suggested edit), so maybe the "suggestions" items got caught up in that change.

Comment: The links still exist btw. [This seems to have been fixed](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/141756/suggested-edits-on-posts-with-100-votes-overflows-the-icon-box) and the links are the same. Not sure why they got removed from the profiles though.

Comment: Well, this is all still in beta (e.g. the address is *stackoverflow.com/ **review-beta** /suggested-edits/548430*) so guess it's a glitch. Hope to see it fixed soon as well and finally deployed!

Comment: This is a bug, I've passed it along for a look. I'm not on the review stuff so not *exactly* sure how the guys want to pull this data once everything's settled, they'll take a look tomorrow though.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is fixed now – the formatting of the "suggestions" user activity subtab has been restored. The only difference is that "suggested edit" links to the new `/review-beta` version of the suggested edit.