# Tracking Low Quality Posts you Recommend Deletion on

Tags: feature-request, review

On the beta [Low Quality Posts task](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts), I can "Recommend Deletion" of answers. It currently doesn't do much, just [move it to the front of the queue for people who can delete it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/139536/new-feature-community-review-tasks-now-in-beta).

To me, deleting a post is pretty serious stuff, so if I "recommend" such an action, I'd like to be able to track the post. I've been doing this by raising "Not an answer" flags, and keeping track of the posts from my Flagging Summary page. Moderators usually handle those flags pretty fast. And seeing if my flags were helpful or not is valuable feedback to me for deciding how to act on future posts.

But, you cannot flag from the Low Quality review queue, and the posts you Recommend Deletion on simply vanish after you click the button and confirm. I understand the beta tool wants to keep things more simple and focused, and probably also reduce the load on moderators. That's great! But we should have a way to track the posts we Recommend Deletion on.

I was thinking it could be shown on `activity > reviews`, together with the suggested edits:

[image]

The red `answer` link would indicate a deleted answer so we can easily spot them. If I Recommend Deletion, and it's still blue after a while, I go back there and flag it.

Do you think that could work? Or maybe we should just have a regular `flag` link on the Low Quality Posts task, like in [the old version](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts)?

---

**UPDATE**

So now the activity tab on my profile is logging more review actions, such as "Close", "Edit" (improve), "Edit" (from low the quality posts task), and "Looks good". But no sign of "Recommend deletion". Will that be added too?

Comment: Why doesn't the activity profile tab show that? It's public information anyway, available from the review queue's history page. So why not show it on the profile too?

Comment: Could this be marked `status-completed`? It was actually implemented months ago.