# Should I flag a low quality answer for deletion when reviewing?

Tags: discussion, flags, review

As I stated on [this other question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/142785/tracking-low-quality-posts-you-recommend-deletion-on), I don't like the way the "Recommend Deletion" works on the new review system, essentially because it doesn't let me know the final outcome of my recommendation.

However, I frequently see answers such as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/36871) on the review queue, and they're very similar to what I see on the 10k flag queue. Is it okay to also flag those posts instead of just recommending deletion, or would I be overloading the moderators for no reason?

Answer (score 2):

For answers like that one you should use the available option from the "Recommend Deletion" popup:

[image]

Comment: I tend not to do that on old answers. But in this case, I think you're right, I just checked the user's profile, and the "last seen" date is 8 hours ago, so that would make sense. Anyway, I'm not asking about this particular case, I'd like to know if it's okay to keep flagging those posts like I'm used to do.