# In the new review beta, what does the "Looks Good" button actually do?

Tags: support, review

In the new(ish) review (for example, for [low-quality posts](https://askubuntu.com/review/low-quality-posts)), what happens behind the scenes when I click the "Looks Good" button?

- Is it just equivalent to following a link to the post in the old review, and then doing nothing with the post?

  My understanding is that doing that just caused the system to record that the post has been reviewed by one (more) user than it had before, and that when a post is reviewed by 2 (or more) users--actioned or not--it is dropped from the review queue.
- Or does it actually "counter-flag" the post, such that any existing flags are indicated (to moderators and 10k users) to have been considered invalid by one (more) user?
- Or does it do something else altogether?

Answer (score 1):

This means you vote to decline the flag - the system identified a post as low quality but you, as high rep user, decide it's not low quality, so dismissing this flag.

Note that low quality flags are automatic - taken from the [official post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/139536/new-feature-community-review-tasks-now-in-beta):

> Low Quality Posts: This task targets posts that we've **algorithmically determined to be low quality**.

So I would say that clicking that button cause the flag to be cancelled, judging from the [review history here on Meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/history) as example it takes one such vote to cancel the flag (at least on Meta), as I can't see two "Looks Good" votes for the same post.

Comment: Interesting, the similar feature from old /review took two votes I thought

Comment: @Ben well, it looks like in the old review system the low quality items are posts that were flagged by users, in the new review system it's automatic algorithm so guess that's the reason one vote is enough.

Comment: Were they? I thought they were the same auto-identified low quality posts in this case. The other stuff (first answers, late answers) were all auto-determined

Comment: @Ben hmm.. not sure! So maybe on the main site it requires two votes, like suggested edits. Really need some official help here, lol. :)

Comment: "*This means you vote to decline the flag*" **But there is** (usually) **no flag.** In both the old and new (beta) review systems, the "low quality" questions are automatically determined. Posts flagged by users as low quality (as well as some automatically determined low quality posts, if the author was prompted with a low-quality dialog but chose to submit the post anyway) go into the *flag* queue (accessible by 10k users), but that's separate.