# What should we do with 'meh' late answers?

Tags: discussion, late-answers

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Reviewing Late Answers - Blah posts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/152659/reviewing-late-answers-blah-posts)

In the late answer queue, I often find things that, under normal circumstances, I'd just leave alone. No vote, no comment, no nothing. To elaborate some cases:

1. Middle of the road answer
2. Middle of the road answer that is not very different from existing answers
3. Answer to poll, shopping, or otherwise currently off-faq question.

One way to think about this: if an answer to an old question with existing answers doesn't add much of anything, does it deserve a downvote as compared to the same answer to the same question without existing answers?

Or, another way to pose this: should there be a 'leave it alone' button on the late answer review, to distinguish 'skip' (because I don't know enough about the subject) from 'meh'?

Comment: We need a “meh” button *and* a “blah” button!