# Useless "add comment" link on answer to locked question

Tags: bug, comments, locked-questions

[This question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/139536/167210), titled "New Feature: Community Review Tasks - Now in Beta", has been locked "for historical relevance".  It's also "community wiki".

I wanted to edit [my answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/139816/167210), but I can't because the question has been locked.

So I decided to add a comment to my own answer.  There's an "add comment" link at the bottom of my answer. When I click it, nothing happens except that the "add comment" link vanishes.  It reappears when I refresh the page.

Since it's not possible to add a comment, the "add comment" link shouldn't be there.

Answers other than mine don't have the "add comment" link; I suspect I see it because it's my answer.

(Sometimes an "add comment" link will show hidden comments; all 7 comments on my answer were already visible.)

(To be clear, this question is not a complaint about the fact that the question has been locked, that I can't edit my answer, or that I can't post a comment; it's just a bug report about the useless "add comment" link.)

[image]

**UPDATE :**

And now the behavior has changed. There's been no new activity on the answer, but now it initially shows two upvoted comments and a "show 5 more comments" link; the link works correctly. Same computer, same browser (Windows 7, Chrome).

Comment: It seems to happen just in the case you are the user who wrote the answer, and your answer has comments that are not visible. Or that, or the issue depends from the browser. I don't see any "add comment" with Safari 6.0 running on OS X 10.8, not even for my own answer.

Comment: @kiamlaluno: There were no hidden comments -- but now they are, and the odd behavior is no longer there.

Comment: Sounds like you got caught between builds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that this problem has been fixed. It now only says "show xx more comments" rather than suggesting that you could add a new comment.