# “Add a Comment” link is available on deleted answer

Tags: bug, comments, deleted-answers

I’ve deleted my own answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/66607772/52277 and then decided to explain why I deleted(I moved my answer to more appropriate question as this question is actually a duplicate).

The “Add a Comment” link was visible, but when I submitted the comment, I received a message “ Cannot add comments to this post; it may be locked, deleted, or frozen”.

If it is not allowed, the “Add a Comment” link should not be visible (or should be disabled).

This bug report is different to [Allow Comments on Deleted Answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/38461/allow-comments-on-deleted-answers), because I am just asking UI to be consistent with the rules, not challenging the rule.

It is similar to [Useless "add comment" link on answer to locked question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/144401/useless-add-comment-link-on-answer-to-locked-question), that seems to be fixed for locked questions, but not for (self-)deleted answers.

Comment: Does the link go away once you reload the page?

Comment: @SebastianSimon, yes, it does

Comment: Then this is by design. It’s similar to [Answer your own deleted question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/405514/4642212) ([<10k screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vph6C.png)).

Comment: @SebastianSimon, The design could not intentionally show the link, that can’t be used. After I deleted the answer, the UI was changed(e.g. show pink background). As a part of this UI change  “Add a Comment” link should become hidden as well

Comment: There’s lots of things that the design _could_ do, but there are more important things that the Stack Exchange devs are worried about, currently, than a link that already provides the correct error message and disappears once the page is reloaded.

Comment: By the way, when explaining deletion, I think you can still edit your deleted posts.

Comment: @SebastianSimon, I’ve reported a bug, that imho is easy to fix, and looks as not good quality UX. It’s up to SE to decide when they want to fix it.

Comment: Regression of [exactly same bug that was fixed long ago](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/190180/requires-50-reputation-to-comment-on-deleted-posts). :/