# Are the review items prioritized by the reviewer's reputation?

Tags: support, review

I've been playing with the new review system for a few days now and I've noticed something about the "Low Quality Posts" section.

It seems that >95% of the posts that I get already have comments left by other reviewers. So nearly everything that I see has already been reviewed (multiple times) by other users.

Not only that, but virtually everything I get is worthy of deletion. (link only, should be a comment, "thank you", etc...) So I find myself burning through my daily quota of 30 delete votes in a very short amount of time.

**So my question is:**

Is the review system intentionally giving me "ready to go" questions because I have vote-to-delete power (to nail the coffin)?

Or are there really that many people reviewing the same posts so that I'm rarely ever the first to see it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Users who can't vote to delete are given a "Recommend deletion" button, which is supposed to move posts to the top of the queue for users who have the ability to delete (see the first footnote on [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/139536/new-feature-community-review-tasks-now-in-beta)).

Given the sheer number of reviewers on Stack Overflow, as [a 20k+ user](https://stackoverflow.com/users/922184/mysticial) it's likely you'll never run into posts that aren't, as you put it, "ready to go".

Comment: Ah... That's a very small footnote that I missed.