# The "Proofreader" badge is now redundant due to the new review system

Tags: feature-request, badges, review, review-badges

The [Proofreader](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/badges/155/proofreader) badge is now redundant because of the introduction of the [new review system](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/139536/new-feature-community-review-tasks-now-in-beta), which awards badges for reviewing a certain number of entries on each of several queues, including suggested edits.  Can someone look into this?

Comment: What's the harm in leaving it alone?

Comment: Nooooooooo... Oh, wait, I already have it, yes it's redundant ;P