# Where is my Proofreader badge?

Tags: support, badges

About 2-3 days ago I have reviewed 100 suggested edits on StackOverflow. But I havent been awarded by [Proofreader](https://stackoverflow.com/badges/1276/proofreader) badge, yet. **Why ?** I know some badges are awarded by automatically scheduled processes but this time is pretty long. If proofreader badge is [redundant](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/150040/197192) or not being awarded anymore why is it still in [badges](https://stackoverflow.com/badges) page?

[image: progress]

Comment: I wonder if the badge includes audits. I noticed that the counter includes audits, which was to me quite unexpected.

Comment: Similar: http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/q/1920

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You *reviewed* 105 items in the queue.

For the badge, you need to have *approved or rejected* 100 suggested edits. The review queue includes [audits](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/157121), and although these count as *reviews*, they do not count towards the badge.

Comment: But from the [activity](http://stackoverflow.com/users/823738/zaffy?tab=activity&sort=reviews) tab, the OP has 144 reviews.

Comment: @BackinaFlash: That includes more than just suggested edits.